# Find partial tuple in list of tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I've a list of tuples

Es:

```
[('a','b','c','d','e'),
 ('f','g','h','i','l'),
 ('m','n','o','p','q'),
 ('r','s','t','u','v'),
 ('z', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad'),
 .....]
```

The length of the tuple is not always the same. In the example is 5 but can change

I've one element (partial tuple) to find.

The length of element is not always the same.

I'm looking for the position of element in tuples.

The length of the element to look for is always less or equal than the length of the tuples.

The order of items to look for is "correct", meaning that cases of type ('m', 'o') does not exist

Es:

```
find ('m','n')
result 2

find ('z','aa','ab')
result 4
```

Comment: Please post sample code for what you've already tried.

Comment: If those are always tuples of strings/characters, you could turn them into strings using e.g. `','.join` and then use `find` to find whether they are contained. With tuples, its a bit more complicated...

Comment: **Not** what I meant.  What I was asking for was for you to show us the actual code you've written to attempt to accomplish this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: find a list within members of another list(in order)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250633/python-find-a-list-within-members-of-another-listin-order)

Comment: Welcome to SO. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As @tobias_k suggested, the simplest way is to convert tuples and subtuples to string, and use the `in` operator for substring check:

```
l = [('a','b','c','d','e'),
          ('f','g','h','i','l'),
          ('m','n','o','p','q'),
          ('r','s','t','u','v'),
          ('z', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad'),
          ...]

def subtuple_index(tuples, t):
    def tuple2str(t): return ',{},'.format(','.join(t))
    t = tuple2str(t)
    for i,x in enumerate(map(tuple2str, tuples)):
        if t in x: return i
    return -1


>>> subtuple_index(l, ('m','n'))
2
>>> subtuple_index(l, ('z','aa','ab'))
4
>>> subtuple_index(l, ('m','o'))
-1
>>> subtuple_index(l, ('z','a'))
-1
```

Comment: Very well !!!! , just one thing
for i , x in enumerate ( map ( lambda x : ' # ' . join ( x ) , l) ) :

l is "tuples" var ??

Comment: you are right. I corrected that typo (and also a major problem with the algorithm ;))

Answer (score -1):

As already suggested, converting your tuples to strings is much easier:

```
tuple_list = [('a','b','c','d','e'),
              ('f','g','h','i','l'),
              ('m','n','o','p','q'),
              ('r','s','t','u','v'),
              ('z', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad'),
              ...]

def find_tuple(tuplist, *partial_elements):
     for tup in tuplist:
         tup_string = ',{0},'.format(','.join(tup))
         if ',{0},'.format(','.join(partial_elements)) in tup_string:
             return tuplist.index(tup)

find_tuple(tuple_list, 'm', 'n') -> 2
find_tuple(tuple_list, 'z', 'aa', 'ab') -> 4
```

Note that this will only return the index of the first tuple it finds in the list where the partial elements are found.

Comment: your algorithm returns 4 for `find_tuple(tuple_list, 'z', 'a')`. that doesn't seem correct

Comment: True. Now it's better :p