# Check for presence of a sliced list in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to write a function that determines if a sublist exists in a larger list.

```
list1 = [1,0,1,1,1,0,0]
list2 = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1]

#Should return true
sublistExists(list1, [1,1,1])

#Should return false
sublistExists(list2, [1,1,1])
```

Is there a Python function that can do this?

Comment: Will your lists always contain only 0 or 1?

Comment: Is this for Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: Ah - I see the gotcha here. You are not looking for something being a subset of the other set - but that it must match in order a slice of the list.

Comment: See also answer using KMP (Knuth-Morris-Pratt) algorithm: [python - Best way to determine if a sequence is in another sequence? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425604/best-way-to-determine-if-a-sequence-is-in-another-sequence)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are sure that your inputs will only contain the single digits 0 and 1 then you can convert to strings:

```
def sublistExists(list1, list2):
    return ''.join(map(str, list2)) in ''.join(map(str, list1))
```

This creates two strings so it is not the most efficient solution but since it takes advantage of the optimized string searching algorithm in Python it's probably good enough for most purposes.

If efficiency is very important you can look at the [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) string searching algorithm, adapted to work on lists.

A naive search has O(n*m) worst case but can be suitable if you cannot use the converting to string trick and you don't need to worry about performance.

Comment: `--` : the code is seriously broken, try `sublistExists([10], [1,0])` == True?!

Comment: @Nas Banov: That's why Mark wrote in his first sentence "If you are sure that your inputs will only contain single characters '0' and '1'..."

Comment: @Tim: But the inputs don't contain "single characters '0' and '1'", mind you! The example shown contains only the numbers `0` and `1` (or "digits" if you will). :)
Besides, his code is slightly more broad - it will handle correct any list of 1-chars or any list of 1-digit numbers (but not both). And it's fairly easy to fix by introducing separator to `str.join`

Comment: I agree with you about Boyer-Moore. I've posted an answer with an implementation.

Comment: @Nas Banov Just to expand on/reiterate your comment, if you replace "" with <some combination of characters that is guaranteed to not appear in the text>, it works. So you do need to determine a separator based on the data, but you don't necessarily have to restrict inputs to single characters.

Answer (score 47):

Let's get a bit functional, shall we? :)

```
def contains_sublist(lst, sublst):
    n = len(sublst)
    return any((sublst == lst[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(lst)-n+1))
```

Note that `any()` will stop on first match of sublst within lst - or fail if there is no match, after O(m*n) ops

Answer (score 4):

No function that I know of

```
def sublistExists(list, sublist):
    for i in range(len(list)-len(sublist)+1):
        if sublist == list[i:i+len(sublist)]:
            return True #return position (i) if you wish
    return False #or -1
```

As Mark noted, this is not the most efficient search (it's O(n*m)). This problem can be approached in much the same way as string searching.

Comment: You should probably avoid using the keyword `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 4):

My favourite simple solution is following (however, its brutal-force, so i dont recommend it on huge data):

```
>>> l1 = ['z','a','b','c']
>>> l2 = ['a','b']
>>>any(l1[i:i+len(l2)] == l2 for i in range(len(l1)))
True
```

This code above actually creates all possible slices of l1 with length of l2, and sequentially compares them with l2.

#### Detailed explanation

*Read this explanation only if you dont understand how it works (and you want to know it), otherwise there is no need to read it*

Firstly, this is how you can iterate over indexes of l1 items:

```
>>> [i for i in range(len(l1))]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

So, because *i* is representing index of item in l1, you can use it to show that actuall item, instead of index number:

```
>>> [l1[i] for i in range(len(l1))]
['z', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Then create slices (something like subselection of items from list) from l1 with length of2:

```
>>> [l1[i:i+len(l2)] for i in range(len(l1))]
[['z', 'a'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c']] #last one is shorter, because there is no next item.
```

Now you can compare each slice with l2 and you see that second one matched:

```
>>> [l1[i:i+len(l2)] == l2 for i in range(len(l1))]
[False, True, False, False] #notice that the second one is that matching one
```

Finally, with function named *any*, you can check if at least one of booleans is True:

```
>>> any(l1[i:i+len(l2)] == l2 for i in range(len(l1)))
True
```

Answer (score 3):

The efficient way to do this is to use the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm), as Mark Byers suggests. I have done it already here: [Boyer-Moore search of a list for a sub-list in Python](https://web.archive.org/web/20220928030405/http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/boyer-moore-search-of-a-list-for-a-sub-list-in-python.html), but will paste the code here. It's based on the Wikipedia article.

The `search()` function returns the index of the sub-list being searched for, or -1 on failure.

```
def search(haystack, needle):
    """
    Search list `haystack` for sublist `needle`.
    """
    if len(needle) == 0:
        return 0
    char_table = make_char_table(needle)
    offset_table = make_offset_table(needle)
    i = len(needle) - 1
    while i < len(haystack):
        j = len(needle) - 1
        while needle[j] == haystack[i]:
            if j == 0:
                return i
            i -= 1
            j -= 1
        i += max(offset_table[len(needle) - 1 - j], char_table.get(haystack[i]));
    return -1

    
def make_char_table(needle):
    """
    Makes the jump table based on the mismatched character information.
    """
    table = {}
    for i in range(len(needle) - 1):
        table[needle[i]] = len(needle) - 1 - i
    return table
    
def make_offset_table(needle):
    """
    Makes the jump table based on the scan offset in which mismatch occurs.
    """
    table = []
    last_prefix_position = len(needle)
    for i in reversed(range(len(needle))):
        if is_prefix(needle, i + 1):
            last_prefix_position = i + 1
        table.append(last_prefix_position - i + len(needle) - 1)
    for i in range(len(needle) - 1):
        slen = suffix_length(needle, i)
        table[slen] = len(needle) - 1 - i + slen
    return table
    
def is_prefix(needle, p):
    """
    Is needle[p:end] a prefix of needle?
    """
    j = 0
    for i in range(p, len(needle)):
        if needle[i] != needle[j]:
            return 0
        j += 1    
    return 1
    
def suffix_length(needle, p):
    """
    Returns the maximum length of the substring ending at p that is a suffix.
    """
    length = 0;
    j = len(needle) - 1
    for i in reversed(range(p + 1)):
        if needle[i] == needle[j]:
            length += 1
        else:
            break
        j -= 1
    return length
```

Here is the example from the question:

```
def main():
    list1 = [1,0,1,1,1,0,0]
    list2 = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
    index = search(list1, [1, 1, 1])
    print(index)
    index = search(list2, [1, 1, 1])
    print(index)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
2
-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way that will work for simple lists that is slightly less fragile than Mark's

```
def sublistExists(haystack, needle):
    def munge(s):
        return ", "+format(str(s)[1:-1])+","
    return munge(needle) in munge(haystack)
```

Comment: @e1i45, have _you_ tried it? What happens when the items in s aren't strings?

Comment: DELIMITER.join(str(x) for x in xs) might work. But maybe it is slower than format?

Answer (score 1):

```
def sublistExists(x, y):
  occ = [i for i, a in enumerate(x) if a == y[0]]
  for b in occ:
      if x[b:b+len(y)] == y:
           print 'YES-- SUBLIST at : ', b
           return True
      if len(occ)-1 ==  occ.index(b):
           print 'NO SUBLIST'
           return False

list1 = [1,0,1,1,1,0,0]
list2 = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1]

#should return True
sublistExists(list1, [1,1,1])

#Should return False
sublistExists(list2, [1,1,1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Might as well throw in a recursive version of @NasBanov's solution

```
def foo(sub, lst):
    '''Checks if sub is in lst.

    Expects both arguments to be lists
    '''
    if len(lst) < len(sub):
        return False
    return sub == lst[:len(sub)] or foo(sub, lst[1:])
```

Comment: Recursion... Can cause a stack overflow on long lists

Comment: @TigranSaluev - stack overflow or maximum recursion depth or RecursionError?

Comment: RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp

Comment: "Might as well"--hmm, why, exactly? This recursive approach seems to have no redeeming qualities compared to the iterative version. It seems longer, less efficient, more error-prone, and less understandable. (I have nothing against recursion in general.)

Comment: @wwii: Alrighty :) I was wondering if you had a particular reason to do it recursively, but it seems it was just because it could be done. Given the recursion depth issue in particular, it does seem like a bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sublist(l1,l2):
  if len(l1) < len(l2):
    for i in range(0, len(l1)):
      for j in range(0, len(l2)):
        if l1[i]==l2[j] and j==i+1:
        pass
      return True
  else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

The function proposed in Nas Banov's answer has a fundamental issue: it creates many lists that are only used to compare portions of the original list.

Specifically, when one writes

```
(sublst == lst[i: i + n]) for i in range(len(lst) - n + 1)
```

then `len(lst) - n + 1` lists of length `n` are created (in the worst case scenario, i.e. when the sublist can't be found in the original list).

There are cases in which this approach could become very slow, especially when the lists to be created are large (i.e., when the sublist is large). For such cases, this implementation is much faster:

```
def is_sublist(sub_lst, lst):
    n = len(sub_lst)
    return any(
        all(lst[i + j] == sub_lst[j] for j in range(n))
        for i in range(len(lst) - n + 1)
    )
```

Let's do a comparison of these two functions (`is_sublist_a` is the one originally proposed by Nas Banov, `is_sublist_b` is the one I'm proposing):

```
def is_sublist_a(sub_lst, lst):
    n = len(sub_lst)
    return any(
        sub_lst == lst[i: i + n]
        for i in range(len(lst) - n + 1)
    )

def is_sublist_b(sub_lst, lst):
    n = len(sub_lst)
    return any(
        all(lst[i + j] == sub_lst[j] for j in range(n))
        for i in range(len(lst) - n + 1)
    )
```

Let's have a look at the worst case scenario (the sublist does not exist). This is the function I use to measure time that a function needs to return the result:

```
from time import time

def exec_time(is_sublist, lst, sub_lst):
    start = time()
    _ = is_sublist(sub_lst, lst)
    return time() - start
```

We can see that, for small sublists, the first function is faster:

```
>>> exec_time(is_sublist_a, [0] * 10**7, [1] * 10)
1.7239012718200684
>>> exec_time(is_sublist_a, [0] * 10**7, [1] * 30)
2.3223540782928467
>>> exec_time(is_sublist_a, [0] * 10**7, [1] * 50)
3.017274856567383

>>> exec_time(is_sublist_b, [0] * 10**7, [1] * 10)
5.492832899093628
>>> exec_time(is_sublist_b, [0] * 10**7, [1] * 30)
5.4729719161987305
>>> exec_time(is_sublist_b, [0] * 10**7, [1] * 50)
5.4685280323028564
```

As you can easily notice, function `is_sublist_a` is faster. But you can also notice that the speed of function `is_sublist_b` does not depend on the length of the sublist, while `is_sublist_a`'s speed does.

So it's easy to show that `is_sublist_b` is much faster than `is_sublist_a` for larger sublists:

```
>>> exec_time(is_sublist_a, [0] * 10**7, [1] * 500)
15.868159055709839
>>> exec_time(is_sublist_a, [0] * 10**7, [1] * 1000)
29.75873899459839

>>> exec_time(is_sublist_b, [0] * 10**7, [1] * 500)
5.8182408809661865
>>> exec_time(is_sublist_b, [0] * 10**7, [1] * 1000)
6.155586004257202
```

Answer (score -2):

I know this might not be quite relevant to the original question but it might be very elegant 1 line solution to someone else if the sequence of items in both lists doesn't matter. The result below will show True if List1 elements are in List2 (regardless of order). If the order matters then don't use this solution.

```
List1 = [10, 20, 30]
List2 = [10, 20, 30, 40]
result = set(List1).intersection(set(List2)) == set(List1)
print(result)
```

Output

```
True
```

Answer (score -4):

if iam understanding this correctly, you have a larger list, like :

```
list_A= ['john', 'jeff', 'dave', 'shane', 'tim']
```

then there are other lists

```
list_B= ['sean', 'bill', 'james']

list_C= ['cole', 'wayne', 'jake', 'moose']
```

and then i append the lists B and C to list A

```
list_A.append(list_B)

list_A.append(list_C)
```

so when i print list_A

```
print (list_A)
```

i get the following output

```
['john', 'jeff', 'dave', 'shane', 'tim', ['sean', 'bill', 'james'], ['cole', 'wayne', 'jake', 'moose']]
```

now that i want to check if the sublist exists:

```
for value in list_A:
    value= type(value)
    value= str(value).strip('<>').split()[1]
    if (value == "'list'"):
        print "True"
    else:
        print "False"
```

this will give you 'True' if you have any sublist inside the larger list.