# Find sub list inside a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers

```
l = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1]]
```

For example , i have to search a pattern '2,1,1,2' , as we can see that is present in row 6 and 7 . 
in order to find that sequence i tried converting each list into str and tried to search the pattern , but for some reason the code isnt working.

```
import re
for i in l:
 if re.search('2,1,1,2' , str(i).strip('[').strip(']')): print " pattern found"
```

am i missing something in here ?

Comment: Is that a string or bunch of lists?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313590/check-for-presence-of-a-sublist-in-python for a very similar question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Converting your list in string is really not a good idea.

How about something like this:

```
def getsubidx(x, y):
    l1, l2 = len(x), len(y)
    for i in range(l1):
        if x[i:i+l2] == y:
            return i
```

Comment: actually the list l has many list as its elements. and converting into string allows me to use reg expressions. but if there is any computational efficiency in this method , then why not !

Comment: +1, regex is really overkill for this problem. Simply looking to see if a sublist matches the query list should be way more efficient.

Comment: well i m kinda very used to reg expressions . Still getting acquainted to pythonic way of coding.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). I suppose you are implicitly assuming that your pattern is present in the list just one time, or you are just interested in knowing if it's in or not.

If you want the list of each first element which starts the sequence, then you can use KMP. Think about it as a sort of string.find() for lists.

I hope this will help.

Comment: very useful @filannim. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2],
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1]]
import re
for i in l:
    if re.search('2, 1, 1, 2' , str(i).strip('[').strip(']')): 
        print " pattern found"
```

`str(list)` will return the string with spaces between the elements... You should look for `'2, 1, 1, 2'` instead of `2,1,1,2`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same idea, without regex

```
data = [
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2],
     [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1],
]

pattern = '2112'

for item in data:
    line = ''
    for number in item:
        line += str(number)
    if pattern in line:
        print 'pattern found: %s' % item
```

Comment: Because strings are immutable, appending using += in this way is slow.  It's better to accumulate the elements of the string in a list and join them at the end - ie replace the inner for loop with this: line = ''.join([str(i) for i in item])