# How do I return the index of multiple elements existing in a list in Python?

Tags: python

```
L=[0,8,5,6,4,5,6,14,8]
```

I want to be able to return the index of [4,5,6] (returning 4 in this example).

Comment: Why are people voting to close? This is a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: I think the not a real question votes are from people who believe you have 0rovided no example code of yours to compare against.  Further a reply from you to someones answer clearly statss your question whereas this shows little to no effort.

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627548/find-sub-list-inside-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
' '.join(map(str,L)).index(' '.join(map(str,x)))/2
```

EDIT: Thanks to isbadawi for noticing the silly mistake, and solilo for pointing out the huge mistake haha

Comment: Seems to have the fastest runtime of all suggested solutions, and it is a one-liner

Comment: `lambda c: str(c)` can be written as just `str`

Comment: Oh yeah you're right duh

Comment: It's just wrong, suppose L = [0, 1, 1], x = [11], x is not in L, and your method will return 1

Comment: @solilo I think it's fine now

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to implement it:

```
def find_in_list(l, x):
    for i in range(len(l) - len(x) + 1):
        if l[i:i+len(x)] == x:
            return i
```

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing; is there a built-in Python function that would make this a short one-liner at all?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [193]: min(i for i in range(len(L)) if L[i:i+len(key)] == key)
Out[193]: 4

In [194]: L=[0,8,5,6,4,5,6,14,8]

In [195]: key=[4,5,6]

In [196]: min(i for i in range(len(L)) if L[i:i+len(key)] == key)
Out[196]: 4
```