# What is an efficient way to find all sub sequences of a given list in python?

Tags: python-3.x

what is the fastest way to find all the sub sequences of a given list in python?

for example

**a=[1,2,2,3]**

sub sequences of a  are  :-

[1],[2],[2],[3],[1,2],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[2,3],[2,2]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all possible sublists of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061686/find-all-possible-sublists-of-a-list)

Comment: Thanks for sharing but I want to find all possible subsequences not sublists.

Comment: Did you try to write some code? What was the problem?

Comment: What about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374626/how-can-i-find-all-the-subsets-of-a-set-with-exactly-n-elements