# Mongoengine Listfield is a sub of a list

Tags: python, compare, mongoengine, sublist, listfield

I have a document

```
class A(Document):
    name = StringField()
    my_list = ListField(StringField())
```

and my class data is:

```
A1.my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
A2.my_list = [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

My condition list is:

```
condition = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

How to I find that A1 has field "my_list" is sub list of my "condition"

P/S: The question is how I can build a Mongoengine Query to do that, I can't find all my records and compare by Python syntax

> Yeah, I found the answer is `$in` in MongoDB and MongoEngine is `__in`
>   You could use:

`A.objects(my_list__in=condition)`

How ever, if your data list is:

```
A1.my_list = [1, 2, 3]
A2.my_list = [1, 6, 7, 8]
```

and condtion list is:

```
condition_list = [1, 9, 10, 11]
```

You could find both is fit. That mean mongoengine will match if there is an element be in both data list and condition list.

> Better solution is $setIsSubset in MongoDB 3
>   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/

I don't think MongoEngine have that feature so if you have this problem, use raw query in MongoEngine to resolve it.

> Another Solution:
>
> ```
> db.a.find({my_list: {"$not": {"$elemMatch": {"$nin" : condition }}}})
> ```
>
> However that double negative make me sick. Any suggestion ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check for presence of a sublist in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313590/check-for-presence-of-a-sublist-in-python)

Comment: Please do a quick search before posting new question, you may find your answer here, anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313590/check-for-presence-of-a-sublist-in-python

Comment: No, it's not Python syntax, I want to know how to build a query in Mongoengine, I can't find all documents in colletions to compare