# How to find if a list is a subset of another list in order?

Tags: python

I know how to find whether a list is a subset of another list. But I was wondering how do you make sure that a list is an ordered subset of another list. By ordered subset I mean that the elements in both the list are in same order

For example if I have the following lists

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [1,2]
C = [2,1]
```

Here B is an ordered subset of A but C is not (although A has all elements of C)

Comment: You could start by writing some code...

Comment: In general, `B` is a sublist of `A` iff `B` is empty or `A` contains the first item of `B` at some position `pos` and the part of `B` past the first item is an ordered sublist of `A` past `pos`. Can you translate that into Python? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313590/check-for-presence-of-a-sublist-in-python

Comment: Can there be gaps?    `[1,2,4]` is a subset of `[1,2,3,4]` with elements in the same order, but it is not a sub-"string", so to speak, because of the 3.  What should your solution do in that case?

Comment: @Jez Yes there can be gaps

Answer (score 5):

```
def is_sub(sub, lst):
    ln = len(sub)
    for i in range(len(lst) - ln + 1):
        if all(sub[j] == lst[i+j] for j in range(ln)):
            return True
    return False
```

Output:

```
In [21]: A = [4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3]

In [22]: B = [1, 2]

In [23]: C = [2, 1]

In [24]: is_sub(B, A)
Out[24]: True

In [25]: is_sub(C, A)
Out[25]: True
In [26]: B = [10,11,12,13,14,15,25]
In [27]: is_sub(B, A)
Out[27]: False
In [39]: A = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
In [40]: B = [1, 2, 3]

In [41]: is_sub(B, A)
Out[41]: True
```

We don't need to worry about the sub being longer than lst as is it is stop will be less that start so we just return False.

You can combine it with any:

```
def is_sub(s, l):
    ln = len(s)
    return any((all(s[j] == l[i + j] for j in range(ln))
                for i in range(len(l) - ln + 1)))
```

Depending on your use case  slicing might be faster:

```
def is_sub(sub, lst):
    ln = len(sub)
    return any(lst[i: i + ln] == sub for i in range(len(sub) - ln + 1))
```

If the elements can have gaps then it is a lot simpler, similar to kfx's you can do it in a single pass or less:

```
def is_sub_with_gap(sub, lst):
    ln, j = len(sub), 0
    for ele in lst:
        if ele == sub[j]:
            j += 1
        if j == ln:
            return True
    return False
```

The fundamental difference being what you consider a subset:

```
In [6]: a,b = [1,2,3,4], [1,2,4]

In [7]: is_sub(b,a)
Out[7]: False

In [8]: is_sub_with_gap(b,a)
Out[8]: True
```

Comment: Both follow-ups (`any` and slicing) will work but both are unnecessarily O(n^2)

Comment: @jez, if the lists are small and the function is called a lot slicing is faster that is why I said *Depending on your use case slicing might be faster*.  The first follow up any is exactly equivalent to the first function.

Comment: But even slicing involves looping over every element of B **for every** element of A, or nearly every element—in contrast to kfx's solution for example, which does the job with a single pass through A. [Ok I should have said O(n*m) rather than n^2]

Comment: @jez, fkx's answer is based on a completely different premise to what the OP had in their question, there were no gaps in the OP's examples which is why I answered using the logic I did and in turn fkx's answer would not have worked in those cases as it would have returned False positives

Comment: is_sub with slicing - len should be of **lst** not sub - range(len(*sub*) - ln + 1)

Answer (score 4):

Use a simple loop to iterate through both lists in order. At the end, check if all elements of the potential subset list have been seen.

```
i,j = 0,0
while i < len(A) and j < len(B):
    if A[i] == B[j]:
        j += 1
    i += 1

has_as_subset = (j == len(B))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that allows gaps (i.e. `is_sublist([1,2,4],[1,2,3,4])` returns `True`) in common with *most* but not all of the other posted solutions; it also handles sublists that start anywhere in the parent list (again, in common with most but not all of the other answers);  also, it returns `False` if the sub-list candidate contains repetition that the master list does not (i.e. `[1,2,2]` is not a sub-list of `[1,2,3]`): again, this property is shared with most but not all of the other answers.   (As far as I can tell the only other solution to hit *all* of these targets is that of kfx.)

```
def is_sublist( sublst, lst ):
    for element in sublst:
        try: ind = lst.index( element )
        except ValueError: return False
        lst = lst[ ind+1: ]
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a_i = 0
for b in B:
    try:
        if b == A[a_i]:
            a_i += 1
    except IndexError:
        return False
return True
```

The basic idea is that you shouldn't exhaust `A` before you exhaust `B`.

Comment: Note that this returns `True` even if B contains repeated items that A does not. For example, if `A=[1,2,3]` and `B=[1,2,2]`.  This may or may not be what the OP wants (unclear from question)

Comment: True. It's unclear if OP means a true subset or not.