# a list as a sublist of a list from group into list

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe, which has 2 columns,

```
    a  b
0   1  2
1   1  1
2   1  1
3   1  2
4   1  1
5   2  0
6   2  1
7   2  1
8   2  2
9   2  2
10  2  1
11  2  1
12  2  2
```

Is there a direct way to make a third column as below

```
    a  b  c
0   1  2  0
1   1  1  1
2   1  1  0
3   1  2  1
4   1  1  0
5   2  0  0
6   2  1  1
7   2  1  0
8   2  2  1
9   2  2  0
10  2  1  0
11  2  1  0
12  2  2  0
```

in which target `[1, 2]` is a sublist of `df.groupby('a').b.apply(list)`, find the 2 rows that firstly fit the target in every group.

---

`df.groupby('a').b.apply(list)` gives

```
1             [2, 1, 1, 2, 1]
2    [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2]
```

`[1,2]` is a sublist of `[2, 1, 1, 2, 1]` and `[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2]`

---

so far,  I have a function

```
def is_sub_with_gap(sub, lst):
    '''
    check if sub is a sublist of lst
    '''
    ln, j = len(sub), 0
    ans = []
    for i, ele in enumerate(lst):
        if ele == sub[j]:
            j += 1
            ans.append(i)
            
        if j == ln:
            return True, ans
    return False, []
```

test on the function

```
In [55]: is_sub_with_gap([1,2], [2, 1, 1, 2, 1])
Out[55]: (True, [1, 3])
```

Comment: Can you explain `[1, 2] is a sublist of df.groupby('a').b.apply(list)` ?

Comment: For me is not clear `[1,2] is a sublist of [2, 1, 1, 2, 1] and [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2]` and why is set `1` to new column?

Comment: @jezrael `[1,2]` is a sublist of `[2, 1, 1, 2, 1]`, I can find row index `[1, 3]`, [`1,2] ` is sublist of `[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2]`, I can find row index `[6, 8]`, I make these rows with 1 to the new column.

Comment: Why `[6,8]` ? And not `[0, 1, (1, 2), (2, 1), 1, 2]` - 3 and 5 ?

Comment: @jezrael https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599113/how-to-find-if-a-list-is-a-subset-of-another-list-in-order, my definition of sublist can be found here.

Comment: Still not understand, I test `print (is_sub([2, 1, 1, 2, 1], [1,2]))
print (is_sub([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2], [1,2]))` and both return `False`

Comment: @jezrael why not  `print (is_sub([1,2], [2, 1, 1, 2, 1])) print (is_sub([1,2], [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2]))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change output by select index values of groups in custom function, flatten it by [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and then test index values by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
L = [1, 2]

def is_sub_with_gap(sub, lst):
    '''
    check of sub is a sublist of lst
    '''
    ln, j = len(sub), 0
    ans = []
    for i, ele in enumerate(lst):
        if ele == sub[j]:
            j += 1
            ans.append(i)
            
        if j == ln:
            return lst.index[ans]
    return []
```

---

```
idx = df.groupby('a').b.apply(lambda x: is_sub_with_gap(L, x)).explode()

df['c'] = df.index.isin(idx).view('i1')
print (df)
    a  b  c
0   1  2  0
1   1  1  1
2   1  1  0
3   1  2  1
4   1  1  0
5   2  0  0
6   2  1  1
7   2  1  0
8   2  2  1
9   2  2  0
10  2  1  0
11  2  1  0
12  2  2  0
```

Comment: `lst.index[ans]`leads to error `'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Is `is_sub_with_gap(lst, x)` corect order?

Comment: tested with `is_sub_with_gap([1,2], [2, 1, 1, 2, 1])`

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon - I think variables in lambda function, changed  it for more clear `L = [1, 2]` and `idx = df.groupby('a').b.apply(lambda x: is_sub_with_gap(L, x)).explode()`

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon - Because it seems there is swapped `x` and `L`

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon - Maybe problem is in my solution in functio `lst` is not list, but `Series`, so working well here

Comment: It works the way you showed. Thanks for your efforts

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon - Thanjk you for patience ;) Happy coding!

Comment: Theoretically speaking, I should get `df[df['c']==1].groupby('a').b.apply(list)` either as `L` or `[]` right?

Comment: yes, then get empty list, so `explode` remove this groups.