# How to find an exact sequence of words in lists using Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am coding in Python 3 on a Windows platform.

I am making a function that will pass in a user's inputted sentence which my function will then `.split()` and make it a list of each word that was in their original sentence.

My function will also pass in a predefined list of word patterns that my function will be watching for as a match on the exact sequence of words appearing in the user's sentence.

Now just so this is clear, I already can use `.intersection()` to find where the exact words are matches **but I am looking for an exact sequence of words**.

For instance if my user inputs: `"I love hairy cats"`, and the predefined list of key words is something like this: `["I love", "hairy cats", "I love cats", "love hair"]`, my function should only indicate `"I love"` and `"hairy cats"` as these two matched the specified sequence of words as they appeared in the predefined lists.

Here is my code thus far:

```
def parse_text(message, keywords):
    newList = []
    Message = message.split()
    Keywords = keywords      # Keywords need to be a list type
    setMessage = set(word for word in Message)
    setKeywords = set(word for word in Keywords)
    newList = setMessage.intersection(setKeywords)

    return newList
```

This works perfectly so far only if my keywords list contains only single words. My issue is when I try to make my list with multiple words to denote the sequence.

If my user's original message is:

```
message = "Hello world, yes and no"

keywords = ["help", "Hello", "yes", "so"]  # this works, intersec "Hello" and "yes"

keywords = ["help me", "Hello mom", "yes and no", "so"]  # this does not work, just returns empty "set()"
```

Any ideas of how I can make adjustments to my function to check my user's original sentence for a specific sequence of words as they appear my keyword list?

Comment: This is not for an assignment, it is for a small program I am trying to make. Basically the user's sentence will actually be in a JSON() dict from an API call to website...but I didn't want to convolute my question with irrelevant details.

Comment: seems like it would be MUCH easier to stringify the list and check for a string within a string.

Comment: @JulienBernu You can't, because it would return also "love hair", because it matched "love hairy", but OP wants to match whole words.

Comment: What about punctuation then? Should `message="Hello, mom"` and `keyword="Hello"` give a match? Because `message.split()` will return `"Hello,"` and not `"Hello"` ...

Comment: Yes, I have encountered this as well but I know I can fix that part later. For now, I am really concerned on matching exact sequence of words as they appear in keywords list. If a punctuation disqualifies, so be it.

Comment: My program will be parsing Slack posts for an exact sequence of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use sets at all? This is a pretty straightforward string operation:

```
def parse_text(message, keywords):
     newList = []
     for keyword in keywords:
         if keyword in message:
             newList.append(keyword)
     return newList
```

or, using list comprehensions for more succinctness:

```
def parse_text(message, keywords):
    return [keyword for keyword in keywords if keyword in message]
```

Finally, one additional form using regular expressions that enforces complete words:

```
from re import search

def parse_text(message, keywords):
     newList = []
     for keyword in keywords:
         if search(r'\b{}\b'.format(keyword), message):
             newList.append(keyword)
     return newList
```

Comment: Basically I am only a novice so far with Python and wasn't aware it was this easy. I really appreciate your help as your recommendation was exactly the answer I required. I have spent the last two days getting my code to somewhat work. You knocked this out in a few minutes. My hat off to you sir!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't knock yourself. It's easy to get thinking of a problem in a direction that makes it a bit harder to solve, and it's often easier for someone outside to see the alternative approach.

Comment: I do not get this. `parse_text("I love hairy cats", ["I love", "hairy cats", "I love cats", "love hair"])` returns `"love hair"` while the author precised it should not.

Comment: You need `r'\b{}\b'`, so you don't match "hairy cats" when you look for "airy cats". Also, `re` solution works as a list comprehension just as well.

Comment: Thanks, I added the missing flag. Yes, it's just a style question of whether or not it's more or less readable as the list comprehension. I agree it's a perfectly valid approach.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done by transforming your keywords list to a list of lists, and then check for lists which are sublist of your message words.

```
def is_sublist(sub_lst, lst):
    n = len(sub_lst)
    return any((sub_lst == lst[i:i + n]) for i in range(len(lst) - n + 1))

message = "Hello world yes and no"
words = message.split()

keywords = ["help me", "Hello mom", "yes and no", "so"]
keywords_lists = [k.split() for k in keywords]
# [['help', 'me'], ['Hello', 'mom'], ['yes', 'and', 'no'], ['so']]

new_sub_lists = [k for k in keywords_lists if is_sublist(k, words)]
new_list = [" ".join(k) for k in new_sub_lists]
# ['yes and no']
```

The `is_sublist` function (inspired from [@Nas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3314913/2291710)) is far from being optimal.

If your are looking for a solution with a small complexity, you should take a look at others [string searching algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm), because your problem can be see like this, with your words being letters.

Comment: This was also helpful as I studied your technique. Seems like I can glean some usefulness from your approach as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
    def parse_text(message, keywords):
        return [kw for kw in keywords if kw in message]
```

Comment: This suggestion also seems to help out. Thank you, appreciated.