# Boolean expression for if list is within other list

Tags: python, list, contains, sub-array

What is a efficient way to check if a list is within another list? Something like:

```
[2,3] in [1,2,3,4]      #evaluates True
[1,5,4] in [5,1,5,4]    #evaluates True
[1,2] in [4,3,2,1]      #evaluates False
```

Order within the list matters.

Comment: Do the elements from the first list need to be consecutive within the second list? For instance, what should `[1,2] in [1,3,2]` return?

Comment: false, because it has to be consecutive

Comment: This question is nothing like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313590/check-for-presence-of-a-sublist-in-python which assumes the data is binary and uses concatenation.  The data here can be any numeric value, e.g. [2, 55, 100].  In this case, the proposed solution in the 'duplicate' question is not applicable.

Comment: @Alexander - The OP of that question did not specify binary data only and there are answers/solutions that would work for *this* data.- specifically the answer with the most votes.

Comment: Actually, the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313590/check-for-presence-of-a-sublist-in-python/3314913#3314913 is the same as this one, and the most upvoted answer there would also work for this (and is coincidentally the same as my answer below).

Comment: @wwii The OP's data is obviously not binary and your answer was not the accepted solution of that question (despite being the most upvoted).  I agree that the most upvoted answer works in this scenario and is about 3x faster than my proposed solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def check_ordered_sublist_in_list(sub_list, main_list):
    sub_list = np.array(sub_list)
    main_list = np.array(main_list)
    return any(all(main_list[n:(n + len(sub_list))] == sub_list) 
               for n in range(0, len(main_list) - len(sub_list) + 1))

>>> check_ordered_sublist_in_list([2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4])
True

>>> check_ordered_sublist_in_list([1, 5, 4], [5, 1, 5, 4])
True

>>> check_ordered_sublist_in_list([1, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1])
False
```

This converts the lists to numpy arrays (for computational efficiency) and then uses slicing to check if the `sub_list` is contained within the slice.  Any success returns True.

Comment: This seems like a misuse of `numpy`. Constructing the `np.array`s is a fairly expensive operation. This will most likely negate whatever computational efficiency is gained by using `numpy` just to perform some simple slices (especially since the lists in the example are very small).

Comment: @pzp Possibly, but the lists are only small in this simple example.  Actual use cases tend to be much more complex. However, I agree that the `is_in` solution proposed by @mfripp is more efficient.

Comment: Using "ordered_sublist" in the function name seems redundant—aren't all lists ordered in Python?

Comment: @martineau Yes, all lists are ordered.  The function title was intended to clarify that [1, 2] is in [1, 2, 3, 4], but [2, 1] is not.  The ordering matters, as clarified by the OP and to distinguish between an unordered collection.  An initial reply incorrectly used sets, for example.

Comment: The OP never asked about unordered collections, only if a list was a sublist of another. Since both are lists, both are ordered by definition.

Comment: @martineau "Order within the list matters." was later added to the question, so I simply added 'ordered' to the function title to clarify that the order of the list was being taken into consideration (vs. treating it as an unordered collection).

Answer (score 2):

You could use this:

```
def is_in(short, long):
    return any(short==long[i:i+len(short)] for i in range(len(long)-len(short)+1))

is_in([2,3], [1,2,3,4])   # True
is_in([1,5,4], [5,1,5,4]) # True
is_in([1,2], [4,3,2,1])   # False
```

If you really care about speed, these expressions are 20-30% faster:

```
def segments(long, length):
    return [long[i:i+length] for i in range(len(long)-length+1)]

def is_in_seg(short, long):
    return short in segments(long, len(short))

is_in_seg([1,5,4], [5,1,5,4])      # true
[1,5,4] in segments([5,1,5,4], 3)  # true
```

And this is 47% faster, but it uses tuples instead of lists:

```
import itertools
def segments_zip(long, length):
    return itertools.izip(*[long[i:] for i in xrange(length)])

(2,3) in segments_zip((1,2,3,4), 2)    # True
(1,5,4) in segments_zip((5,1,5,4), 3)  # True
(1,2) in segments_zip((4,3,2,1), 2)    # False
```

The extra speed comes from using itertools.izip, which can stop generating segments when a match is found; from using xrange, which avoids creating the whole range list; and from using tuples, which are generally slightly faster than lists. But the tiny speed advantage will vanish if you have to convert lists to tuples to use it.