# How to click hotkey and open specific url in python?

Tags: python, pynput

Click the sequence of buttons, like <kbd>shift+a</kbd> and open amazon.com. Click another sequence of buttons, like <kbd>shift+e</kbd> and open `ebay.com`.
The code works for `amazon.com` but when I click hotkey <kbd>shift+e</kbd> it is not open ebay.com.
When you print key which you are clicking you realize that program is pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd> and <kbd>a</kbd>.
I don't know why program prints <kbd>a</kbd> which I do not click?

```
import time
from pynput import keyboard
COMBINATIONS = [
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='a')},
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='A')},
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='e')},
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='E')}
]
current = set()

def execute(url):
    keyboard_ctrl = keyboard.Controller()
    keyboard_ctrl.press(keyboard.Key.ctrl_l)
    keyboard_ctrl.press('l')
    keyboard_ctrl.release(keyboard.Key.ctrl_l)
    keyboard_ctrl.release('l')
    time.sleep(0.2)

    for i in url:
        keyboard_ctrl.press(i)
        keyboard_ctrl.release(i)
    # keyboard_ctrl.type(url)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    keyboard_ctrl.press(keyboard.Key.enter)
    keyboard_ctrl.release(keyboard.Key.enter)

def on_press(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.add(key)
        print(key)
        if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
            if keyboard.KeyCode(char='a') in current and keyboard.Key.shift in current:
                execute('https://www.amazon.com/')
            if keyboard.KeyCode(char='e') in current and keyboard.Key.shift in current:
                execute('https://www.ebay.com/')

def on_release(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        if key in current:
            current.remove(key)

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: please, choose only one tag or a general [tag:python] tag

Answer (score 0):

First, it would be better and simpler to just clear `current` after a combination instead of removing item after key release. Second `all(k in current for k in COMBO)` would only check if all elements in `COMBO` exist in `current`, not the orientation. For example, if you press <kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> it would become `True` which is wrong in here.
A solution is to use `list` instead of `set` and check if the `COMBO` exists (as a slice) in `current`. I used [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313590/check-for-presence-of-a-sliced-list-in-python) for checking the existence of a slice list.

```
import time
from pynput import keyboard
COMBINATIONS = [
    [keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='a')],
    [keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='A')],
    [keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='e')],
    [keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='E')]
]
current = []


def execute(url):
    keyboard_ctrl = keyboard.Controller()
    keyboard_ctrl.press(keyboard.Key.ctrl_l)
    keyboard_ctrl.press('l')
    keyboard_ctrl.release(keyboard.Key.ctrl_l)
    keyboard_ctrl.release('l')
    time.sleep(0.2)

    for i in url:
        keyboard_ctrl.press(i)
        keyboard_ctrl.release(i)
    # keyboard_ctrl.type(url)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    keyboard_ctrl.press(keyboard.Key.enter)
    keyboard_ctrl.release(keyboard.Key.enter)


def contains_sublist(lst, sublst):
    n = len(sublst)
    return any((sublst == lst[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(lst)-n+1))


def on_press(key):
    global current
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.append(key)
        print(key)
        if any((contains_sublist(current, COMBO)) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
            print("Combination pressed!")
            if current[-1] == keyboard.KeyCode(char='a'):
                execute('https://www.amazon.com/')
            if current[-1] == keyboard.KeyCode(char='e'):
                execute('https://www.ebay.com/')
            current = []


with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```