# Check for presence of a sublist in list with order kept, and allow wildcards

Tags: python, list

I want to check if a sublist is present in another (larger) list, in the exact same order of elements. I also want it to allow wildcards. For example I have the following lists:

```
>>> my_lists
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

And the sublist: `[0, 0, 0, 1]`. If I want to find which lists contain this exact sublist I can do (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313590/check-for-presence-of-a-sliced-list-in-python)):

```
def my_func(_list, sub_list):
    n = len(sub_list)
    return any((sub_list== _list[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(_list)-n+1))

for l in my_lists:
    if my_func(l, [0, 0, 0, 1]):
        print(l)
```

... which basically makes all possible sublists of the same length as the `sub_list`, and checks whether or not any are equal. And I would get the following output since these lists contain `[0, 0, 0, 1]`:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Now I also want to add wildcards, meaning that I can give the sublist wildcard elements. For example, now I want to find the sublist `[*, *, 0, 0, 0, 1, *]`. The asterisks here mean that for those elements, the value could be anything in the list. But for those asterisks **there must be a value**. The sublist `[*, *, 0, 0, 0, 1, *]` would now output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Note that now `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` is not included since this list doesn't have two values before the `[0, 0, 0, 1]` sequence starts. The same goes for `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]`, which also doesn't have two values before the sequence. Note that the asterisk could be anything such as np.nan.

How would I extend above code to allow for the wildcards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `all` when checking against sublists and an `if` that skips asterisks:

```
def my_func(a_list, sub_list):
    n = len(sub_list)

    # list-level comparison is now via element-wise
    return any(all(sub_item == chunk_item
                   for sub_item, chunk_item in zip(sub_list, a_list[i:i+n])
                   if not np.isnan(sub_item))  # "is_not_asterisk" condition
               for i in range(len(a_list)-n+1))
```

where I used `not np.isnan(...)` as the asterisk condition as mentioned in the question; but it could be many things: e.g., if asterisk is literally `"*"` in sublists, then the condition there is changed to `if sub_item != "*"`.

sample with `np.nan` as asterisk:

```
for a_list in my_lists:
    if my_func(a_list, [np.nan, np.nan, 0, 0, 0, 1, np.nan]):
        print(a_list)
```

gives

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

---

`all` returns `True` if the iterable is empty so if an all-asterisk sub-list is passed, it will return `True` for all candidates (as long as their length permits, which `any` will handle because `any` with empty iterable is `False`!).

Comment: Thanks! I like this solution the most since it's clean and easy to comprehend.

Answer (score 2):

If we create a `SuperInt` class that allows us to wrap `int` but make it equal to another instance with a same value (or a 'normal' `int` with the same value) **and** the string `'*'`, we can use the same code you already have.

```py
WILDCARD = '*'

class SuperInt(int):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, self.__class__) and other == WILDCARD:
        # or
        # if isinstance(other, str) and other == '*': but there might be a caveat with that
            return True
        return super().__eq__(other)
```

Converting your `my_lists` to use `SuperInt` instances:

```py
for i, li in enumerate(my_lists):
    my_lists[i] = list(map(SuperInt, li))
```

running the *exact* same code you already have (just replacing `*` with `WILDCARD` as defined above):

```py
def my_func(_list, sub_list):
    n = len(sub_list)
    return any((sub_list == _list[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(_list)-n+1))

for l in my_lists:
    if my_func(l, [WILDCARD, WILDCARD, 0, 0, 0, 1, WILDCARD]):
        print(l)
```

Outputs

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks DeepSpace! I never thought about super classing `Int`, interesting solution.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, with custom compare function:

```py
def custom_cmp(l1, l2):
    if len(l1) != len(l2):
        return False

    for a, b in zip(l1, l2):
        if a == "*":  # you can check here for b=='*' if you wish
            continue
        if a != b:
            return False

    return True


def my_func(_list, sub_list):
    n = len(sub_list)
    return any(
        custom_cmp(sub_list, _list[i : i + n])
        for i in range(len(_list) - n + 1)
    )


for l in my_lists:
    if my_func(l, ["*", "*", 0, 0, 0, 1, "*"]):
        print(l)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the elements in your lists are always single character (such as numbers in your example), you can convert to string and search your motif using the [re](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/re.html) module.
This is more than 10 times faster than @Mustafa Aydın answer, and in my opinion quite fast to write as a one liner. But of course it doesn't work on datasets with multi-character elements.

```
import re
[l for l in my_lists if re.search('..0001.', ''.join(map(str, l)))]
```

Alternatively, using [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
list(filter(lambda l: re.search('..0001.', ''.join(map(str, l))), my_lists))
```

If you need to input your query as a list with the proposed format for wildcards:

```
pattern = ['*', '*', 0, 0, 0, 1, '*']
[l
 for l in my_lists
 if re.search(''.join(map(str, pattern)).replace('*', '.'),
              ''.join(map(str, l)))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered, but here's another option that I like to think of as 'old school.'

```
my_lists = [
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]

my_sub_list = [0, 0, 0, '*', 1]

def my_function(_list, _sub):
    a = len(_list)
    b = len(_sub)
    x = 0                                              # sublist index
    y = 0                                              # list index
    while y < a:
        if (_sub[x] == _list[y]) or (_sub[x] == '*'):  # we have a match
            x += 1                                     # increment sublist index counter
            y += 1                                     # increment list index counter
            if x == b:                                 # if sublist index equals sublist length, then we've found a match
                print(_list)
                return
        else:
            if x > 0:                                   # We had a partial match
                y -= x - 1                              # Resetting index counter to next index after previous match
            else:
                y += 1                                  # No match, so we're moving to the next index
            x = 0                                       # Resetting sublist index to the beginning


for l in my_lists:
    my_function(l, my_sub_list)
```