# How to test if a list contains another list as a contiguous subsequence?

Tags: python

How can I test if a list contains another list (ie. it's a contiguous subsequence). Say there was a function called contains:

```
contains([1,2], [-1, 0, 1, 2]) # Returns [2, 3] (contains returns [start, end])
contains([1,3], [-1, 0, 1, 2]) # Returns False
contains([1, 2], [[1, 2], 3]) # Returns False
contains([[1, 2]], [[1, 2], 3]) # Returns [0, 0]
```

Edit:

```
contains([2, 1], [-1, 0, 1, 2]) # Returns False
contains([-1, 1, 2], [-1, 0, 1, 2]) # Returns False
contains([0, 1, 2], [-1, 0, 1, 2]) # Returns [1, 3]
```

Comment: For what it's worth, returning `[start, end+1]` is more pythonic as it looks like a slice -- `(end+1)-start` gives the length of what is found.

Comment: This looks like a bad design - sometimes the function returns a bool, sometimes it returns a list.  That makes it very hard to use since you have to check the return type before you can do anything with the result.  IMHO a function called "contains" should only return True or False.

Comment: It's kinda sad that lists don't have the needed functionality built-in, but strings do (`str.find`).

Comment: Why would this, for any reason, return a list and not a tuple!?

Comment: related: [Best Way To Determine if a Sequence is in another sequence in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/425604/4279)

Comment: Returning `False` is questionable since `False == 0`, and `0` is a valid `start`, so that could be confusing. Instead, I'd raise a `ValueError`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check for presence of a sliced list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313590/check-for-presence-of-a-sliced-list-in-python)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Here is my version:

```
def contains(small, big):
    for i in xrange(len(big)-len(small)+1):
        for j in xrange(len(small)):
            if big[i+j] != small[j]:
                break
        else:
            return i, i+len(small)
    return False
```

It returns a tuple of `(start, end+1)` since I think that is more pythonic, as Andrew Jaffe points out in his comment.  It does not slice any sublists so should be reasonably efficient.

One point of interest for newbies is that it uses the [else clause on the for statement](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) - this is not something I use very often but can be invaluable in situations like this.

This is identical to finding substrings in a string, so for large lists it may be more efficient to implement something like the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer_moore).

**Note:** If you are using Python3, change `xrange` to `range`.

Comment: +1 for the note about efficient string searching algorithms. One disadvantage of yours is the addition of an interpreted inner loop (the slice comparison is, I imagine, faster, although the copy might offset that). I'm going to try a performance comparison.

Comment: After further tests, yours *is* the best so far for large subsequences. I would pick this, even despite the small disadvantage is has on smaller data sets.

Comment: +1: Didn't know about `for`'s `else` clause! Just today I created an awkward construct involving setting a boolean to do exactly this.

Comment: I think it's simpler to use slicing, similar to [martineau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3847612/4518341): `if big[i:i+len(small)] == small: return i, i+len(small)`.

Comment: You can save on calculating `len(small)` over and over by defining it at the top, like `n = len(small)`

Comment: I am surprised that there is no mention of KMP algorithm which has the best *worst time complexity* of O(n).

Comment: Amazing that there are *two* higher-voted answers that solve *completely unrelated* problems. I guess the accept button has *some* value....

Answer (score 103):

If all items are unique, you can use sets.

```
>>> items = set([-1, 0, 1, 2])
>>> set([1, 2]).issubset(items)
True
>>> set([1, 3]).issubset(items)
False
```

Comment: that's not what op is looking for

Comment: It would work for unique lists. In fact it would work for non-unique items, but it wouldn't be able to determine between the individual items. (so you couldn't compare between [1, 1, 2] and [1, 2].)

Comment: Okay, that's why I used the qualifier "if all items are unique." I didn't realise, as your example didn't make it clear that you needed distinction between identical items.

Comment: It still won't work, even if all items are unique, unless they are also in the same order, with no intermingled items.  e.g. finding `[1, 3]` or `[2, 1]` in `[1, 2, 3]` will give a false positive.  Assuming that we're looking for the sequence itself rather than just the values contained in the sequence.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for pointing that out. eumiro's answer looks better then.

Comment: @Thomas O  When you post an answer that is a) wrong, b) not what OP is looking for or C) all of the above, there is a 'delete' link at the bottom left of your post. feel free to click it and 1) declutter the thread, 2) avoid exposing yourself to further -1's.

Comment: I think it's better to show how an idea can be wrong (so as to avoid it in future), rather than erasing it entirely.

Comment: Yes, especially since this is the correct solution for some people (like me) who find this page, who do not care about sequence.

Comment: Note to viewer: the results provided in this example is not accurate.  That being said, this example helped me out.

Comment: @mk12 sucks for people like me who do and the first 2 questions I've been on no one cares about the order

Comment: @intuited IDK what version of python did you use but with python3.10 if items are in random order everything works fine, no false positives `set([3, 1]).issubset(set([1, 2, 3, 4]))  # True`

Answer (score 55):

There's an `all()` and `any()` function to do this.
To check if `big` contains ALL elements in `small`

```
result = all(elem in big for elem in small)
```

To check if `small` contains ANY elements in `big`

```
result = any(elem in big for elem in small)
```

the variable result would be boolean (TRUE/FALSE).

Comment: If I am not mistaken `all(elem in list1 for elem in list2)` is testing all items in list2 against items in list1 so it is other way around. This checks list2 contains all items in list1

Comment: `all(elem in big for elem in small)` would return true regardless of position, which isn't what OP wants. They asked for "contiguous subsequence".

Comment: In case anyone confused , here is example

`ColumnToCheck = [1,2,3,4]
ListofItems =[1,2,3,4,251,54,8,65,5,85,25]

#if all items  from ColumnToCheck exist in ListofItems
print(all(x in ListofItems  for x in ColumnToCheck))`

Comment: Seems to have answered the wrong question.

Answer (score 6):

May I humbly suggest the [Rabin-Karp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm) if the `big` list is really big. The link even contains almost-usable code in almost-Python.

Answer (score 5):

This works and is fairly fast since it does the linear searching using the builtin [`list.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) method and `==` operator:

```
def contains(sub, pri):
    M, N = len(pri), len(sub)
    i, LAST = 0, M-N+1
    while True:
        try:
            found = pri.index(sub[0], i, LAST) # find first elem in sub
        except ValueError:
            return False
        if pri[found:found+N] == sub:
            return [found, found+N-1]
        else:
            i = found+1
```

Comment: Not sure if there is a flaw can you matineau double check. I tried print (contains((1,2,3),(1,2,3))) and I got [0,2] instead of [0,1,2]

Comment: @user-asterix: The function is effectively returning `[start, end]` as designed (and OP wants).

Answer (score 5):

> I've Summarized and evaluated Time taken by different techniques

##### Used methods are:

```
def containsUsingStr(sequence, element:list):
    return str(element)[1:-1] in str(sequence)[1:-1]


def containsUsingIndexing(sequence, element:list):
    lS, lE = len(sequence), len(element)
    for i in range(lS - lE + 1):
        for j in range(lE):
            if sequence[i+j] != element[j]: break
        else: return True
    return False


def containsUsingSlicing(sequence, element:list):
    lS, lE = len(sequence), len(element)
    for i in range(lS - lE + 1):
        if sequence[i : i+lE] == element: return True
    return False


def containsUsingAny(sequence:list, element:list):
    lE = len(element)
    return any(element == sequence[i:i+lE] for i in range(len(sequence)-lE+1))
```

##### Code for Time analysis (averaging over 1000 iterations):

```
from time import perf_counter

functions = (containsUsingStr, containsUsingIndexing, containsUsingSlicing, containsUsingAny)
fCount = len(functions)


for func in functions:
    print(str.ljust(f'Function : {func.__name__}', 32), end='   ::   Return Values: ')
    print(func([1,2,3,4,5,5], [3,4,5,5]) , end=', ')
    print(func([1,2,3,4,5,5], [1,3,4,5]))



avg_times = [0]*fCount
for _ in range(1000):
    perf_times = []
    for func in functions:
        startTime = perf_counter()
        func([1,2,3,4,5,5], [3,4,5,5])
        timeTaken = perf_counter()-startTime
        perf_times.append(timeTaken)
        

    for t in range(fCount): avg_times[t] += perf_times[t]

minTime = min(avg_times)
print("\n\n Ratio of Time of Executions : ", ' : '.join(map(lambda x: str(round(x/minTime, 4)), avg_times)))
```

##### Output:

[image: Output]

#### Conclusion: In this case, Slicing operation proves to be the fastest

Answer (score 4):

If we refine the problem talking about testing if a list contains another list with as a sequence, the answer could be the next one-liner:

```
def contains(subseq, inseq):
    return any(inseq[pos:pos + len(subseq)] == subseq for pos in range(0, len(inseq) - len(subseq) + 1))
```

Here unit tests I used to tune up this one-liner:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6910a85b4978daee137f

Comment: I think this is the answer for me!  nice one-liner, looks right.

Comment: incidentally though, I think `return True` might pass all those unit tests.

Answer (score 3):

After OP's edit:

```
def contains(small, big):
    for i in xrange(1 + len(big) - len(small)):
        if small == big[i:i+len(small)]:
            return i, i + len(small) - 1
    return False
```

Comment: But it fails with contains([1,2], [-1, 0, 1, 1, 2]) which returns [2,4] instead of what I assume is the expected [3,4]

Comment: This is going to be horribly inefficient for big lists, since it is constantly creating and destroying temporary lists every time it does `big[i:i+len(small)]`

Comment: @Dave: did you timeit this against your solution?

Comment: According to my tests, this has slightly better performance than Dave Kirby's solution, even on large lists (1 million elements, with the matching subset at the end): 4.1s for 10 repetitions versus 5.6s for Dave's. I would love to post my test code, but there isn't an easy way to do that.

Comment: @Tim Yates: Could you post your test code in a [gist](gist.github.com) or other pastebin-type deal?  Maybe [codepad](codepad.org) would be a better option, though I don't know if running it on that site would be a) possible; b) reliable.  It seems to be borken at the moment anyway.

Comment: **UPDATE**: I spoke too soon--my small lists were too small. This algorithm exploded once I increased their size to 1000, while the others stayed constant. It looks like Dave Kirby's wins for large lists after all. http://pastebin.com/NZwU6PUx

Comment: This should return a tuple, not a list. A list is completely inappropriate for this usage. Corrected in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward algorithm that uses list methods:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def list_find(what, where):
    """Find `what` list in the `where` list.

    Return index in `where` where `what` starts
    or -1 if no such index.

    >>> f = list_find
    >>> f([2, 1], [-1, 0, 1, 2])
    -1
    >>> f([-1, 1, 2], [-1, 0, 1, 2])
    -1
    >>> f([0, 1, 2], [-1, 0, 1, 2])
    1
    >>> f([1,2], [-1, 0, 1, 2])
    2
    >>> f([1,3], [-1, 0, 1, 2])
    -1
    >>> f([1, 2], [[1, 2], 3])
    -1
    >>> f([[1, 2]], [[1, 2], 3])
    0
    """
    if not what: # empty list is always found
        return 0
    try:
        index = 0
        while True:
            index = where.index(what[0], index)
            if where[index:index+len(what)] == what:
                return index # found
            index += 1 # try next position
    except ValueError:
        return -1 # not found

def contains(what, where):
    """Return [start, end+1] if found else empty list."""
    i = list_find(what, where)
    return [i, i + len(what)] if i >= 0 else [] #NOTE: bool([]) == False

if __name__=="__main__":
    import doctest; doctest.testmod()
```

Answer (score 1):

Smallest code:

```
def contains(a,b):
    str(a)[1:-1].find(str(b)[1:-1])>=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer. This function will help you to find out whether B is a sub-list of A. Time complexity is O(n).

```
`def does_A_contain_B(A, B): #remember now A is the larger list
    b_size = len(B)
    for a_index in range(0, len(A)):
        if A[a_index : a_index+b_size]==B:
            return True
    else:
        return False`
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make this as efficient as possible.

It uses a generator; those unfamiliar with these beasts are advised to check out [their documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators) and that of [yield expressions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions).

Basically it creates a generator of values from the subsequence that can be reset by sending it a true value.  If the generator is reset, it starts yielding again from the beginning of `sub`.

Then it just compares successive values of `sequence` with the generator yields, resetting the generator if they don't match.

When the generator runs out of values, i.e. reaches the end of `sub` without being reset, that means that we've found our match.

Since it works for any sequence, you can even use it on strings, in which case it behaves similarly to `str.find`, except that it returns `False` instead of `-1`.

As a further note: I think that the second value of the returned tuple should, in keeping with Python standards, normally be one higher.  i.e. `"string"[0:2] == "st"`.  But the spec says otherwise, so that's how this works.

It depends on if this is meant to be a general-purpose routine or if it's implementing some specific goal; in the latter case it might be better to implement a general-purpose routine and then wrap it in a function which twiddles the return value to suit the spec.

```
def reiterator(sub):
    """Yield elements of a sequence, resetting if sent ``True``."""
    it = iter(sub)
    while True:
        if (yield it.next()):
            it = iter(sub)

def find_in_sequence(sub, sequence):
    """Find a subsequence in a sequence.

    >>> find_in_sequence([2, 1], [-1, 0, 1, 2])
    False
    >>> find_in_sequence([-1, 1, 2], [-1, 0, 1, 2])
    False
    >>> find_in_sequence([0, 1, 2], [-1, 0, 1, 2])
    (1, 3)
    >>> find_in_sequence("subsequence",
    ...                  "This sequence contains a subsequence.")
    (25, 35)
    >>> find_in_sequence("subsequence", "This one doesn't.")
    False

    """
    start = None
    sub_items = reiterator(sub)
    sub_item = sub_items.next()
    for index, item in enumerate(sequence):
        if item == sub_item:
            if start is None: start = index
        else:
            start = None
        try:
            sub_item = sub_items.send(start is None)
        except StopIteration:
            # If the subsequence is depleted, we win!
            return (start, index)
    return False
```

Comment: A valiant effort, but this has worse performance than either eumiro or Dave Kirby's solutions. 8.2s on the benchmark I described in the other comments.

Comment: Interesting to see the speed difference for native code.  It seems like this algorithm would be relatively faster for longer subsequences.. how long was/were the subsequence(s) you used in the test?

Comment: You're right. This performed much better than eumiro's solution with larger subsequences, but it still didn't perform as well as Dave's.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is fast...

```
def issublist(subList, myList, start=0):
    if not subList: return 0
    lenList, lensubList = len(myList), len(subList)
    try:
        while lenList - start >= lensubList:
            start = myList.index(subList[0], start)
            for i in xrange(lensubList):
                if myList[start+i] != subList[i]:
                    break
            else:
                return start, start + lensubList - 1
            start += 1
        return False
    except:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[[1,2] , [3,4] , [0,5,4]]
print(a.__contains__([0,5,4]))
```

It provides true output.

```
a=[[1,2] , [3,4] , [0,5,4]]
print(a.__contains__([1,3]))
```

It provides false output.

Comment: This seems version specific. For example, it fails on LeetCode.

Answer (score 0):

Dave answer is good. But I suggest this implementation which is more **efficient** and doesn't use nested loops.

```
def contains(small_list, big_list):
    """
    Returns index of start of small_list in big_list if big_list
    contains small_list, otherwise -1.
    """
    loop = True
    i, curr_id_small= 0, 0
    while loop and i<len(big_list):
        if big_list[i]==small_list[curr_id_small]:
            if curr_id_small==len(small_list)-1:
                loop = False
            else:
                curr_id_small += 1
        else:
            curr_id_small = 0
        i=i+1
    if not loop:
        return i-len(small_list)
    else:
        return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple and efficient function to check whether big list contains a small one in matching order:

```py
def contains(big, small):
    i = 0
    for value in big:
        if value == small[i]:
            i += 1
            if i == len(small):
                return True
        else:
            i = 1 if value == small[0] else 0
    return False
```

Usage:

```
"""
>>> contains([1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4])
True
>>> contains([4,2,3,2,4], [2,3,4])
False
>>> contains([1,2,3,2,3,2,2,4,3], [2,4,3])
True
"""
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem of most of the answers, that they are good for unique items in list. If items are not unique and you still want to know whether there is an intersection, you should count items:

```
from collections import Counter as count

def listContains(l1, l2):
  list1 = count(l1)
  list2 = count(l2)

  return list1&list2 == list1

print( listContains([1,1,2,5], [1,2,3,5,1,2,1]) ) # Returns True
print( listContains([1,1,2,8], [1,2,3,5,1,2,1]) ) # Returns False
```

You can also return the intersection by using `''.join(list1&list2)`

Answer (score -1):

Here a solution with less line of code and easily understandable (or at least I like to think so).

If you want to keep order (match only if the smaller list is found in the same order on the bigger list):

```
def is_ordered_subset(l1, l2):
    # First check to see if all element of l1 are in l2 (without checking order)
    if not set(l1).issubset(l2): 
        return False

    length = len(l1)
    # Make sublist of same size than l1
    list_of_sublist = [l2[i:i+length] for i, x in enumerate(l2)]
    #Check if one of this sublist is l1
    return l1 in list_of_sublist
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use numpy:

```
def contains(l1, l2):
   """ returns True if l2 conatins l1 and False otherwise """

   if len(np.intersect1d(l1,l2))==len(l1):
      return = True
   else:
      return = False
```