# Python: Why Lists do not have a find method?

Tags: python, string, list, methods

I was trying to write an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847386/testing-if-a-list-contains-another-list-with-python/3848928#3848928) and was quite surprised to find out that there is no find method for lists, lists have only the index method (strings have find and index).

Can anyone tell me the rationale behind that?
Why strings have both?

Comment: This question is about the list equivalent of this: `"112131".find("1213") => 1` ie `[1,1,2,1,3,1].find([1,2,1,3]) => 1` -- If you want to do this *in linear time* you need to implement one of the string matching algorithms yourself, which is not that easy.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why or maybe is buried in some PEP somewhere, but i do know 2 very basic "find" method for lists, and they are `array.index()` and the `in` operator. You can always make use of these 2 to find your items. (Also, re module, etc)

Comment: `index` method and `in` operator can look for single items in lists (Somebody please tell me if I can call them atomic). OP wants to know if he can find whether a list is a sub-list of another with items appearing in the same order.

Comment: But the basic principle behind is also iteration through the list, whether its nested or not,  and finding them with these operators. OP is also free to develop own method/classes/generators etc for that.

Comment: The standard `find` method for arrays is to search for a single item.  Nobody would be surprised to learn that an array implementation doesn't do substring searches.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: With Python's otherwise very thorough treatment of lists, and its insistence on strings being treated similar to lists, I do find it surprising.

Answer (score 4):

I think the rationale for not having separate 'find' and 'index' methods is they're not different enough. Both would return the same thing in the case the sought item exists in the list (this is true of the two string methods); they differ in case the sought item is not in the list/string; however you can trivially build either one of find/index from the other. If you're coming from other languages, it may seem bad manners to raise and catch exceptions for a non-error condition that you could easily test for, but in Python, it's often considered more pythonic to shoot first and ask questions later, er, to use exception handling instead of tests like this (example: [Better to 'try' something and catch the exception or test if its possible first to avoid an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604636/better-to-try-something-and-catch-the-exception-or-test-if-its-possible-first)).

I don't think it's a good idea to build 'find' out of 'index' and 'in', like

```
if foo in my_list:
   foo_index = my_list.index(foo)
else:
    foo_index = -1 # or do whatever else you want
```

because both in and index will require an O(n) pass over the list.

Better to build 'find' out of 'index' and try/catch, like:

```
try:
    foo_index = my_list.index(foo)
catch ValueError:
    foo_index = -1 # or do whatever else you want
```

Now, as to why list was built this way (with only index), and string was built the other way (with separate index and find)... I can't say.

Answer (score 2):

The "find" method for lists is `index`.

I do consider the inconsistency between `string.find` and `list.index` to be unfortunate, both in name and behavior: `string.find` returns -1 when no match is found, where `list.index` raises ValueError.  This could have been designed more consistently.  The only irreconcilable difference between these operations is that `string.find` searches for a string of items, where `list.index` searches for exactly one item (which, alone, doesn't justify using different names).

Comment: try `"asdfasdf".index('z')` next time your in an REPL.

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth: It highlights the absurdity of the oft-parroted "one obvious way to do something", when they can't even hold to it for core string methods.

Comment: but the point of my example is that they _do_ hold to it. `list` and `string` both have an `index` method that behaves exactly the same. it's just that `string` adds a `find` method on top of that. I'm not sure why they don't do it for `list` as well but there is no equivalence between `list.index` and `string.find`.

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth: The inconsistency is just shifted a little, with the underlying cause being the redundant search functions.  (`getattr` handles this properly, allowing both a sentinel or an exception depending on what's needed.)

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth, although `string` and `list` both have an `.index()` method, it doesn't do quite the same thing. For strings it will find substring, but a sublist of a list -- which to me is another example of the inconsistency.

Comment: @marineau, that's a great point. I suppose I'm wrong. not the first time by a mile

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth. How can you see and respond to my comment before I even hit the 'Add Comment' button? It really throws me off and now I can't fix the typos in it.