# Python: try-except vs if-else to check dict keys

Tags: python, if-statement, try-catch

I came across code which I somehow find 'odd'.

```
var = None
try:
  var = mydict[a][b]
except:
  pass
```

I'm not very comfortable with using `try-except` for checking `dict` key, when obviously there is an `if-else` sequence to handle the same situation.

```
var = None
if a in mydict:
    if b in mydict[a]:
        var = mydict[a][b]
```

Is there any 'obvious' advantage/disadvantage of using one approach over the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Better to 'try' something and catch the exception or test if its possible first to avoid an exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604636/better-to-try-something-and-catch-the-exception-or-test-if-its-possible-first)

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604636/better-to-try-something-and-catch-the-exception-or-test-if-its-possible-first?rq=1). Short answer - python favors try/except although it's not absolute. Specifically in this case, a catch-all `except` is a pretty bad idea. You would want to use `except KeyError` to isolate it.

Comment: Also interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11360880/1193075

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exception handling is generally much slower than an if statement. With the presence of nested dictionaries, it is easy to see why the author used an exception statement. However, the following would work also.

```
var = mydict.get(a,{}).get(b,None)

if var is None:
   print("Not found")
else:
   print("Found: " + str(var))
```

The use of `get` on the `dict` object returns a default value when the key is not present.

Comment: Is the exception handling also slower, if we specify the `KeyError` exception here?

Answer (score 3):

Just to note that in this scenario you can go for:

```
var = mydict.get(a, {}).get(b)
```

Answer (score 3):

One disadvantage arises from the fact that the 2 snippets are **not equal**, the first is a blanket statement which says that *no matter what happens, stay quite*.

To make them equal, modify the first snippet to catch just the `KeyError` :

```
var = None
try:
  var = mydict[a][b]
except KeyError:
  pass
```

---

As they stand, the second snippet will crash if something other than `KeyError` happens, the first one will keep going, and that is perhaps inviting more problems.