# Testing variables/functions with try/exception

Tags: python

Instead using if/else to test a variable or function , using try/exception  like described bellow would be more pythonic?

```
def fufu(oi):
    try:
        int(oi)
    except:
        raise
    else:
        return True

some_var = 1
try:
    some_var
except NameError:
    print("some_far not defined, boo hoo")
else:
    try:
        fufu(some_var)
    except:
        print("i'm not a guitarr, so i don't accept string,")
    else:
        print("Thank you for the integer: {}".format(some_var))
    finally:
        print("we're done")
finally:
    print("test finished")
```

Comment: No, that code is not Pythonic. `fufu` seems pretty pointless, you're using bare `except`s and you're making assumptions you shouldn't (*whatever* goes wrong in `fufu` it must be because the argument was a string?) What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: @jonrsharpe now fufu tests int/string, the code is just an example about if i can use try/except instead of if/else to test results.... plus, the code was just an example to ask if i could use try/exept instead of if/else to test results.

Comment: what do you mean *"test results"*? I certainly wouldn't write unit tests like that - use e.g. [`unittest.assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises). And there's absolutely no point to the `except: raise` in `fufu`.

Comment: probably not really a duplicate, but if...else vs try...except is convered pretty well in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7604717/238310).

Comment: @jonrsharpe damn.. it's frustrating not having english as a primary language... because i'm really struggling to try to explain my question. i'll update the question for a more basic example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, using try/except statements instead of if/else conditional statements to *test a condition* is not Pythonic.

---

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and [PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) are the touchstones for what is considered "Pythonic". PEP 20 states:

> Simple is better than complex.
>
> [...]
>
> Readability counts.

It would generally be agreed that conditional statements are simpler, more readable, and the expected way to test a condition in your code.

Comment: thank you for addressing to the exact point of this question :)