# Reason not to use a guarded/constrained collection

Tags: java, collections, constraints, predicate

Is there any reasons/arguments not to implement a Java collection that restricts its members based on a predicate/constraint?

Given that such functionality should be necessary often, I was expecting it to be implemented already on collections frameworks like apache-commons or Guava. But while [apache indeed had it](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#predicatedCollection(java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate)), Guava [deprecated its version of it](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/ade2447175691ce35fa184714e667810fdffe9ee/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Constraints.html) and recommend not using similar approaches.

The [Collection interface contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add-E-) states that a collection may place any restrictions on its elements as long as it is properly documented, so I'm unable to see why a guarded collection would be discouraged. What other option is there to, say, ensure a Integer collection never contains negative values without hiding the whole collection?

Comment: I think the problem with these Collection implementations is that they are really only views on preexisting collections. The original collection can be modified - a non-compliant member can be added - so the view isn't really a guaranteed solution. I don't see a good reason why a truly constrained collection would be a bad idea. But this is a great question and I don't truly know.

Comment: What would happen if you tried to put an element in a collection and it rejects it?

Comment: @dcsohl The same argument could be given for `Collections.unmodifiable*(...)` collections (although one could argue whether this is not just an implication of certain language-specific shortcomings). @biziclop Interestingly, the `add` method already allows throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` for the case that *"...some property of the element prevents it from being added to this collection"*. So I also don't see a profound technical reason to not use such a collection.

Comment: @biziclop Certainly I'm yet to have that experience for anything other than null. But if there is a reason not to accept it (say, errors further down the road) than it's better to fail ASAP. Using an access method may be clearer but the convenience of a collection would be lost as a price.

Comment: The deprecation comment indicates that [Preconditions](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/master/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) are the replacement for Constraints.

Comment: @gcscaglia I think the argument of the Guava deprecation comment is that you should do this check **before** you attempt to add the element to the collection, that doing this in the `add()` method of the collection is already kicking it down the road.

Comment: @Marco13 I was merely curious. `IllegalArgumentException` makes sense in these cases and indeed `TreeSet` is implemented in a way that rejects non-comparable elements if it doesn't have an explicit comparator. So I see no technical reason not to do it.

Comment: Such a `List` could potentially be inefficient. For example `Collections.swap` would check the predicate on both items, even though they were both already in the `List`. You couldn't override this behaviour as it's `static`. This could have a significant impact on the performance of `Collections.sort`, for example.

Comment: @biziclop Indeed, `add()` is further down in that case. But I can't see an approach that will let me both expose a nice collection interface and keep the validation encapsulated in the right class. I'll have to expose a collection-like behavior no matter what, so I would rather leverage the Collection/List interface.

Comment: @gcscaglia Well, you can really, if you want to. It's just that for whatever reason the Guava developers didn't find it a common enough problem (or a good enough solution) to keep it in their library.

Answer (score 3):

It is just a matter of preference -look at thread about [checking before vs checking after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604636/better-to-try-something-and-catch-the-exception-or-test-if-its-possible-first) - I think that is what it boils down to. Also checking only on `add()` i good enough only for immutable objects.

Comment: Good point about immutable objects. Though you can argue that `HashSet` can only be used for immutable objects too (or at least objects with an immutable `hashCode()`) and yet it's part of the class library.

Comment: Ouch, I really missed the possibility of the object changing after being added. And in my use case it _is_ a possibility. The positive Integers where just an example. Ty for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>There can hardly be **one** ("acceptable") answer, so I'll just add some thoughts:</sub>

As mentioned in the comments, the [`Collection#add(E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add-E-) already allows for throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`, with the reason

> if some property of the element prevents it from being added to this collection

So one could say that this case was explicitly considered in the design of the collection interface, and there is no obvious, profound, purely technical (interface-contract related) reason to not allow creating such a collection.

---

However, when thinking about possible application patterns, one quickly finds cases where the observed behavior of such a collection could be ... counterintuitive, to say the least.

One was already mentioned by dcsohl in the comments, and referred to cases where such a collection would only be a *view* on another collection:

```
List<Integer> listWithIntegers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

List<Integer> listWithPositiveIntegers = 
    createView(listWithIntegers, e -> e > 0);

//listWithPositiveIntegers.add(-1); // Would throw IllegalArgumentException
listWithIntegers.add(-1); // Fine

// This would be true:
assert(listWithPositiveIntegers.contains(-1));
```

However, one could argue that

- Such a collection would not necessarily have to be only a *view*. Instead, one could enforce that only *new* collections with such constraints may be created
- The behavior is similar to that of [`Collections.unmodifiableCollection(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableCollection-java.util.Collection-), which is widely anticipated as it is. (Although it serves a *far* broader and omnipresent use-case, namely avoiding the internal state of a class to be exposed by returning a modifiable version of a collection via an accessor method)

But in this case, the potential for "inconsistencies" is much higher.

For example, consider a call to [`Collection#addAll(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-). It also allows throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` *"if some property of an element of the specified collection prevents it from being added to this collection"*. But there are no guarantees about things like atomicity. To phrase it that way: It is not specified what the *state* of the collection will be when such an exception was thrown. Imagine a case like this:

```
List<Integer> listWithPositiveIntegers = createList(e -> e > 0);

listWithPositiveIntegers.add(1); // Fine
listWithPositiveIntegers.add(2); // Fine
listWithPositiveIntegers.add(Arrays.asList(3,-4,5)); // Throws

assert(listWithPositiveIntegers.contains(3)); // True or false?
assert(listWithPositiveIntegers.contains(5)); // True or false?
```

(It may be subtle, but it may be an issue).

All this might become even trickier when the *condition* changes after the collection has been created (regardless of whether it is only a view or not). For example, one could imagine a sequence of calls like this:

```
List<Integer> listWithPredicate = create(predicate);
listWithPredicate.add(-1); // Fine 
someMethod();
listWithPredicate.add(-1); // Throws
```

Where in `someMethod()`, there is an innocent line like

```
predicate.setForbiddingNegatives(true);
```

One of the comments already mentioned possible performance issues. This is certainly true, but I think that this is not really a *strong* technical argument: There are no formal complexity guarantees for the runtime of any method of the `Collection` interface, anyhow. You don't know how long a `collection.add(e)` call takes. For a `LinkedList` it is O(1), but for a `TreeSet` it may be O(n log n) (and who knows what `n` is at this point in time).

Maybe the performance issue and the possible inconsistencies can be considered as special cases of a more general statement:

**Such a collection would allow to basically *execute arbitrary code* during many operations - depending on the implementation of the predicate.**

This may literally have arbitrary implications, and makes reasoning about algorithms, performance and the exact behavior (in terms of consistency) impossible.

---

The bottom line is: There are many *possible* reasons to not use such a collection. But I can't think of a strong and general *technical* reason. So there may be application cases for such a collection, but the caveats should be kept in mind, considering how exactly such a collection is intended to be *used*.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that such a collection would have too many responsibilities and violate SRP.

The main issue I see here is the readability and maintainability of the code that uses the collection. Suppose you have a collection to which you allow adding only positive integers (`Collection<Integer>`) and you use it throughout the code. Then the requirements change and you are only allowed to add odd positive integers to it. Because there are no compile time checks, it would be much harder for you to find all the occurrences in the code where you add elements to that collection than it would be if you had a separate wrapper class which encapsulates the collection.

Although of course not even close to such an extreme, it bears some resemblance to using `Object` reference for all objects in the application.

The better approach is to utilize compile time checks and follow the well-established OOP principles like type safety and encapsulation. That means creating a separate wrapper class or creating a separate type for collection elements.

For example, if you really want to make quite sure that you only work with positive integers in a context, you could create a separate type `PositiveInteger extends Number` and then add them to a `Collection<PositiveInteger>`. This way you get compile time safety and converting `PositiveInteger` to `OddPositiveInteger` requires much less effort.

Enums are an excellent example of preferring dedicated types vs runtime-constrained values (constant strings or integers).