# How to prevent itemfreq() function from crashing when it encounters an empty numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I'm attempting to use the itemfreq() function from scipy to count the frequencies of unique elements in numpy arrays.

Basically, I've declared a variable (let's call it "A") that outputs a numpy array. Depending on earlier inputs, "A" may contain anywhere from 0 to 13 elements. When "A" contains at least 1 element, the itemfreq() functions works perfectly, but if "A" is empty, I get the following error:

```
IndexError: index out of bounds.
```

I'd like to be able to write a simple statement like this:

```
if A = []: print ("Sorry, your array is empty")
else: print (itemfreq(A))
```

But I'm not sure how to say that first line of code ("if A is an empty array") in python-speak.

Thanks!

Comment: `if not A` would do the trick

Comment: Use try ... except ...

Comment: `scipy.stats.itemfreq([])` happily returns me a `(0, 2)` empty array (using either scipy v0.14.1 or v0.16.1). Perhaps the exception is being raised somewhere else - could you show the full traceback in your question?

Comment: If you can, update scipy to a newer version.  The error you're getting was fixed in 0.14; the latest released version of scipy is 0.16.1.  You can check the version you have with `import scipy; print scipy.__version__`.

Answer (score 0):

Catch exception with try ... except clause :

```
try:
    print(itemfreq(A))
except IndexError:
    print("Sorry, your array is empty")
```

You should prefer `try-except` over an `if/else`

[Better to 'try' something and catch the exception or test if its possible first to avoid an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604636/better-to-try-something-and-catch-the-exception-or-test-if-its-possible-first)

[Using try vs if in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835756/using-try-vs-if-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I would formulate it as

```
if len(A) == 0:
    print ("Sorry, your array is empty")
```

or

```
try:
    print (itemfreq(A))
except LookupError:
    print ("Sorry, your array is empty")
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty list/arrays have zero length:

```
if len(A) == 0:
    print ("Sorry")
```