# list index out of range scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

        for each_div in soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "trapac-form-view-results tpc-results" }):

            if each_div.findAll("table", {"class": "sticky-enabled table-select-processed tableheader-processed sticky-table"})[1]:
                for child0 in each_div.findAll("table", {"class": "sticky-enabled table-select-processed tableheader-processed sticky-table"})[1]:

                    if child0.name == "table":
                         print("2")
                         child = child0.findChildren()

                         for child in child0:
                             if child.name == "tbody":
                                 child1 = child.findChildren()
```

the code above perfectly fine but when the `table[1]` tag is not available it gives me `IndexError`

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

i tried try n catch not succeeded

how i can put condition in such a way that if table[1] does not exist i should be out of complete loop and look for next variable

help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pythonic way to do this is using `try/except` (but not `if` and of course not `len`!)

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

    for each_div in soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "trapac-form-view-results tpc-results" }):

        try:
            node = each_div.findAll("table", {"class": "sticky-enabled table-select-processed tableheader-processed sticky-table"})[1]
        except IndexError:
            continue

        for child0 in node:

            if child0.name == "table":
                 print("2")
                 child = child0.findChildren()

                 for child in child0:
                     if child.name == "tbody":
                         child1 = child.findChildren()
```

There are [several reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604636/better-to-try-something-and-catch-the-exception-or-test-if-its-possible-first) why this way is the best one.

Comment: Thanks a lot with couple of changes code is working fine, the idea of try n catch is what i was looking for, thank again

Answer (score 0):

The method *findAll* returns a list containing all matching elements, meaning that if the length of the list is 0 then no tables could be matched. By checking that the length is greater than 1 you can be certain that there's at least two table elements that matched (since you use that second element found by *findAll*).

By storing the result in a variable you can also avoid doing duplicate work (i.e. calling *findAll* twice).

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

for each_div in soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "trapac-form-view-results tpc-results" }):
    tables = each_div.findAll("table", {"class": "sticky-enabled table-select-processed tableheader-processed sticky-table"})
    if len(tables) > 1:
        for child0 in tables[1]:

            if child0.name == "table":
                 print("2")
                 child = child0.findChildren()

                 for child in child0:
                     if child.name == "tbody":
                         child1 = child.findChildren()
```