# Conditional string representation based on variable type

Tags: python, string, date, datetime, format

I would like to create a string representation of a `datetime` object that could contain a `None` value. So far, I came up with a solution, but I was looking at a better/cleaner way of doing it.

Let's say I have the following two variables:

```
import datetime as dt

a = None
b = dt.datetime(2017, 11, 30)


def str_format(str):
    return '{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(str)
```

The following would return a formatted string:

```
str_format(b)
'2017-11-30'
```

But the following would return an error:

```
str_format(a)
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__
```

So far I can up with the following solution:

```
def str_format(str):
    if isinstance(str, type(None)) is False:
        return '{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(str)
    else:
        return '{}'.format(str)

str_format(a)
'None'

str_format(b)
'2017-11-30'
```

However, I was looking at a more efficient/cleaner way of writing the function.

Comment: I think that it is better to test if your parameter is type of datetime.
`isinstance(b, dt.datetime)`, you're sure that you format the right type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function is overcomplex. `None` is a singleton, so the pythonic way of testing against it is just `is None`.

Just do it in one line with a ternary expression:

```
def str_format(s):
   return str(s) if s is None else '{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(s)
```

or to return a default date (ex: 1/1/2010) if `None` is passed:

```
def str_format(s):
   return '{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(s or dt.datetime(2010, 1, 1))
```

as a side note don't use `str` as a variable name as it is the python string type.

Answer (score 2):

Often times these types of things are wrapped in a `try/except`

```
def str_format(str):
  try:
    return '{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(str)
  except TypeError:
    # unrecognized type, return blank or whatever you want to return
    return ''
```

The answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604636/better-to-try-something-and-catch-the-exception-or-test-if-its-possible-first) question explains why you typically use `try/except` instead of a conditional check fairly well.