# Is there a Pythonic way to handle object chains that could contain None?

Tags: python, django

My Django codebase has foreign key references that are a few objects deep and it feels like a code smell to have to check for truthiness at each level.

Is there a way to check for this kind of thing in a more pythonic way with less boilerplate?

Take this simplified example:

```
if page.banner.image:
    # ...
```

If `page.banner` is optional and it doesn't exist it will return `None` and throw an exception saying, rightly, that `NoneType` doesn't have an `image` attribute.

The obvious fix is

```
if page.banner and page.banner.image:
    # ...
```

But this will get repetitive and verbose.  I suppose you could use `getattr()` to do something like I'm after but it's even uglier:

```
if getattr(getattr(page, 'banner', None), 'image', None):
    # ...
```

Is there a concise way to do this without all these conditional clauses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python recommends the [easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html?highlight=eafp#term-eafp) approach.

```
try:
    new_var = page.banner.image
except AttributeError:
    ....
```

There is some good discussion about asking permission vs forgiveness [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604636/better-to-try-something-and-catch-the-exception-or-test-if-its-possible-first).

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Feels a little weird to be using a bunch of `try..except` blocks, though.

Comment: Yeah, I need to take that to heart more. Thanks!