# Traceback error with startswith

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I keep getting a traceback error saying `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'` when I get to the end of my script. What I am doing up to this point is scraping all kinds of different pages then pulling all these different pages into one list that scrapes the final URL for each business page. What I did was go to `each_page` and scrape all the `'a'` tags off of the page, then I am wanting to search through them and only keep the ones that start with `'/401k/'`. I know I could probably do it without having to add it to another list because I feel like I have too many. I was thinking of doing it like this:

```
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    href = a.get('href')
    if href.startswith('/401k/'):
        final_url.append(href)
        #Even when I try this I get an error saying that no attribute
```

Either way it isn't getting the data and I cant figure out what is going on. Maybe I've been looking at the screen too much.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.brightscope.com/ratings/"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
hrefs = []
ratings = []
pages = []
s_names = []
final_url = []

for href in soup.findAll('a'):
    if 'href' in href.attrs:
        hrefs.append(href.attrs['href'])
for good_ratings in hrefs:
    if good_ratings.startswith('/ratings/'):
        ratings.append(url[:-9]+good_ratings)

del ratings[0]
del ratings[27:]

for each_rating in ratings:
    page = requests.get(each_rating)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    span = soup.find('span', class_='letter-pages')
    if soup.find('span', class_='letter-pages'):
        for a in span.find_all('a'):
            href = a.get('href')
            pages.append('https://www.brightscope.com'+href)
    else:
        pages.append(page.url)
hrefs = []
pages = set(pages)
for each_page in pages:
    page = requests.get(each_page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    for a in soup.findAll('a'):
        href = a.get('href')
        s_names.append(href)
    # I am getting a traceback error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith' starting with the code below.
    for each in s_names:
        if each.startswith('/401k'):
            final_url.append(each)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because you are trying to use the `startswith` operator irrespective of whether the value is present or not. You should first check if the `each` variable is having value or not. Try this

```
for each in s_names:
    if each and each.startswith('/401k'):
        final_url.append(each)
```

What the above statement is doing is, first it is checking if the value is `None` or not . Then if the value is not `None` then it is moving forward to make the check using `startswith`

Comment: I think the real question is why on the first place he's adding `None`s to this list

Comment: @Hagai Yes that is one point. But again it is completely upto him on that logic. It might be possible that he might be wanting to add all the `a` tags. My solution focuses on solving the error which he is getting and not changing his base logic. On a broader aspect the OP should know how to fix such issue and while writing code he should be able to write code which can handle such situation. With the approach you suggested, he would be able to solve it, but would again be stuck on some other  `'NoneType' object has no attribute` problem introduced due to some other logic

Comment: @argo Great movie btw - Argo. It looks like this does work well. I am running it right now and it hasn't given me any errors.

Comment: @argo I ran this code and I didn't get a traceback error. I did, however, grab ALL the links even ones that didn't start with `/401k/`

Comment: All the links in final_url or in hrefs?

Answer (score 1):

`a` tags can have no `href` in html 5 so `a.get('href')` returns `None`. that's probably what you're experiencing.
What you need is to make sure you don't get `None`:

```
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
href = a.get('href')
if href is not None:
    s_names.append(href)
```

See here for more details https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element

> If the a element has no href attribute, then the element represents a placeholder for where a link might otherwise have been placed, if it had been relevant, consisting of just the element’s contents.

Comment: This makes more sense! We can't expect every `a` tag to have `href`, so making the script to handle the exception is a better option. @Hagai, i would suggest to use `try except` instead of `if else` as it consumes lesser time comparatively. (reference:https://stackoverflow.com/a/7604717/3488550)

Comment: @SmashGuy how would you use try except cleanly here? nothing throws exception here...

Comment: I mentioned a custom exception here. If an `a` tag happens to enter without `href`, isn't that an exception to be thrown?

Comment: @SmashGuy as far as I know `a.get('href')` will return None, and will not throw an exception. You can raise an exception yourself, but it probably complicates the code un-necessarily.

Comment: I did not suggest that for your code. I suggested for @Kamikaze_goldfish code like including .startswith() within `try except` block.