# Python Var in def

Tags: python

I made a input inside of a def function but need to use it in an if statement outside of the def function 
But it says the input is not defined

```
def mainmenu()
       Pick = input("input 1 for deposit, and so on")

If pick == "1":
   Deposit()
```

Comment: Variable is only defined in the scope method, you may return it

Comment: `Pick " input(` is not valid syntax.  Did you mean `pick = input`?

Comment: Yes i mean pick = input

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of "global" keyword in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python)

Comment: @Cartoonzstr Do you see my answer? Explains pretty well....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the variable `pick` is only a local variable (one inside a function) and not a global variable (one that can be accessed everywhere), you have to return it to access the variable globally.

```
def pick():
  pick = input("input 1 for deposit, and so on")
  return pick

if pick() == "1":
  Deposit()
  # and so on...
```

Thus, you can access it by running the function. Then check if it is equal to one.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what you're trying to do, but based on your example, you can use:

```
def pick():
   return input("input 1 for deposit, and so on")

if pick() == "1":
   # Deposit()
   print("execute Deposit()")
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/44891782bf)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this is  better approach
instead to use if statement

```
menu_data = { '1' : func1, '2': func2} # etc...


def pick():
    user_input = input("input 1 for deposit, and so on")
    try:
      menu_data[user_input]() # call the method according to the input
    except KeyError as err:
        print('invalid key try again')
        pick()
```

Comment: you don't need to check the input, the try catch handle it and you can call your function again to ask the user to enter again a valid input

Comment: Python encourages the use of exceptions, which you handle

Comment: you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604636/better-to-try-something-and-catch-the-exception-or-test-if-its-possible-first

Comment: delete all comments, forget this whole thing