# Check if model from sklearn.ensemble has been fitted to data

Tags: python, exception, scikit-learn

Check if `RandomForestClassifier` object have been fitted to data. I can catch `NotFittedError` from `sklearn.exceptions` but is there better way? And in general we can't then is relaying on error catching good practice in Python ?

Comment: you can use check_is_fitted method: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.validation.check_is_fitted.html

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way to check sklearn estimators is the `check_is_fitted` utility function, although that too will raise the `NotFittedError` on failure.  [Docs pages.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.validation.check_is_fitted.html)  That function mostly looks for "fitted attributes" that end in an underscore, so if you want to check specifically for `RandomForestClassifier`, maybe you should just check for `hasattr(model, "estimators_")`?

As to whether try-except'ing is pythonic, see e.g. [Using 'try' vs. 'if' in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1835756/10495893) and [Better to 'try' something and catch the exception or test if it's possible first to avoid an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7604636/10495893).