# incrementing an integer inside an array gives me TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, arrays, increment

I have an array that looks like the following: ["string", int , [] ] but when I try to increment the int Python gives me an error. (by the way I am new to python so this might be a simple question)

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Here is my problematic part of the code:

```
for line in responseid_container:
    if line[0] is log.id_resp_address:
        ipFound = True
        #--- this line is where I get an exception ---
        responseid_container[1] += 1
        responseid_container[2].append = log.id_resp_address
```

(example for responseid_container = ['54.192.11.194', 1, [0]])

I tried to look for an answer in many places, such as: [here](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwizms71vLjOAhXEPRQKHc33B98QFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F9304408%2Fhow-to-add-an-integer-to-each-element-in-a-list&usg=AFQjCNFRcYKSljn1JFC0vM2fUNqgLqHiew),[here](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwizms71vLjOAhXEPRQKHc33B98QFgghMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F18325312%2Fhow-to-create-a-range-of-numbers-with-a-given-increment&usg=AFQjCNGV6H0QfryvJ7fffYC_jLOM_re0cQ),[here](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwizms71vLjOAhXEPRQKHc33B98QFggoMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F16903264%2Fbasic-python-how-to-increase-value-of-item-in-list&usg=AFQjCNE30Pabs7GiLpLUTSiIGyDFHKwgqg), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941288/how-do-i-fix-typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable) , and many more... I hope it is not a duplicated answer but I did try and find if it is :-)

Here is my full code of the class if needed

```
from reader import fullLog

class counters:
    local_logs = []
    arrange_by_response_id = []

    def __init__(self , fulllog):
        self.local_logs = fulllog


    def arrangebyresonseid(self):
        responseid_container = [[" " , 0 , []]]
        ipFound = False
        counter = 0

        for log in self.local_logs.oopList:
            for line in responseid_container:
                if line[0] is log.id_resp_address:
                    ipFound = True
                    responseid_container[1] += 1
                    responseid_container[2].append = log.id_resp_address

                if not ipFound:
                    ipFound = False
                    responseid_container.append([log.id_resp_address , 1 , [counter]])

                counter += 1
```

Comment: Appending to the container inside the loop you are iterating within it is bad practice and can cause bugs. Also, for what line do you get the error?

Comment: It's kind of hard to see what is generating the error, do you have a line number? But generally having an array of mixed types is a bad idea. For that I might recommend a tuple

Comment: Hey Doron, thanks on the quick response!
what should I add to my code? an actual example of responseid_container? or an actual example of all variables?

Comment: thanks clement!
I will now study what is a tuple, it may solve the problem

Comment: I add an example for responseid_container = ['54.192.11.194', 1, [0]] as you can see I am trying to increment the number 1 (second place in the array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code you have problem at this statement:-

```
responseid_container[1] += 1
```

convert this line to:-

```
responseid_container[0][1] += 1
```

Check it carefully:-

```
responseid_container = [
                          0 => [
                            0 => " " , 1 => 0 , 2 => []
                          ]
                       ]
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh!
Yes you are right, it was a silly mistake from my side.
also thanks on the effort