# What should I do when I get int object is not iterable?

Tags: python

```
 def filter_list_by_value(self):
        self.get_user_input("Insert number to filter by: ")
        value = int(self.__user_input)
        print(value)
        new_list = list()
        try:
            self.history_stack.append(str(self.expense_list))
            for item in self.expense_list:
                try:
                    new_list.append(list(filter(lambda val: val > value, item.expense)))
                except TypeError as te:
                    print("type error" , te)
            self.expense_list = new_list
        except TypeError as te:
            print("Type error!", te)
```

class Expense:
    def **init**(self, expense: int, category: str, day: int):
        self.__expense = expense
        self.__category = category
        self.__day = day

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self)


def __str__(self):
    return str(self.__dict__)


@property
def day(self):
    return self.__day

@day.setter
def day(self, day):
    self.__day = day

@property
def expense(self):
    return self.__expense

@expense.setter
def expense(self, expense):
    self.__expense = expense

@property
def category(self):
    return self.__category

@category.setter
def category(self, category):
    self.__category = category
```

I keep getting 'int' object is not iterable. What should I do? expense_list is an class-made object.

Comment: What is `item.expense`?

Comment: Please check out this post from stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941288/how-do-i-fix-typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable

Comment: i have a getter in the repo called expense. I made it with [at]property
Thought that would work

Comment: The thing is that all I am trying to access is an object and that's what's bugging me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by:

```py
new_list = list()
...
new_list.append(list(...))
...
self.expense_list = new_list
```

self.expense_list has to be a list of lists. However, by:

```
for item in self.expense_list:
    ...
    item.expense
```

It cannot be, since lists don't have an expense attribute. Please verify you have all your datatypes straight.

Comment: Well i thought I could call the expense getter from the repo.
class Expense:
    def __init__(self, expense: int, category: str, day: int):
        self.__expense = expense
        self.__category = category
        self.__day = day

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)
    [at]property
    def expense(self):
        return self.__expense

    [at]expense.setter
    def expense(self, expense):
        self.__expense = expense

Comment: Could you edit that into your question? That's useful information. Along with any other ways expense_list can be constructed. Because this code looks like several errors competing to come first.