# I am new to Python and I wonder what is wrong with this code

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I wonder what is wrong with this code, I searched for this,I guess in the end of the make_list function I have to return, and not print(). and in the end I have to write
`if name[0]`  and not `if name[1]`, but what else is wrong with it?

**Code:**

```
def make_list(number):
    names = []
    for item in number:
        names.append(input("Enter your name with a capital letter."))
        print(names)
        
number = int(input("How many names need to be entered?"))
names = make_list(number)
for name in names:
    if name [1] == 'A':
        print("Name", name, "starts with A")
```

**Compiler says:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
File "<string>", line 3, in make_list
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `number` is an int, so `for item in number` does not make sense. Also `make_list` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Should be `for item in range(number):`

Comment: Python doesn't know what e.g. `for item in 3` is supposed to mean. In for loop, you need some kind of iterable, so e.g. [0, 1, 2], which you can get by using `range(3)`

Comment: Potential Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941288/how-do-i-fix-typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941288/how-do-i-fix-typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have [`range(numbers)`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp) to iterate, and you also forgot to `return names` from the `make_list` function. Also, as the arrays in Python are [zero-indexed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), you probably want to check `if name [0]`

```py
def make_list(number):
    names = []
    for item in range(number):
        names.append(input("Enter your name with a capital letter."))
        print(names)
    return names
        
number = int(input("How many names need to be entered?"))
names = make_list(number)
for name in names:
    if name [0] == 'A':
        print("Name", name, "starts with A")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
def make_list(number):
    names = []
    for _ in range(number):
        names.append(input("Enter your name with a capital letter: "))
        print(names)
    return(names)
        
number = int(input("How many names need to be entered? "))
names = make_list(number)
for name in names:
    if name.startswith('A'):
        print("Name", name, "starts with A")
```

Results:

```
How many names need to be entered?3
Enter your name with a capital letter.RUNE
['RUNE']
Enter your name with a capital letter.PETER
['RUNE', 'PETER']
Enter your name with a capital letter.ANDERS
['RUNE', 'PETER', 'ANDERS']
Name ANDERS starts with A
```

Comment: This also works, good answer, however I would suggest changing the return statement from the function from: `return(names)` to just `return names`

Comment: _Generally the convention would be to not use brackets on a return statement_

Answer (score 1):

In python you can not loop through an integer. Try to switch `for item in number` with `for item in range(number)` I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: This is not the only problem, the other issue that @user23952 also addressed is that the `make_list` function is not returning `names` as well as the correction from `if name[1] =='A'` to `if name[0]=='A'`. I don't know why this has an upvote when it clearly only fixes one part of the problem and the correct answer has already been posted by @user23952 here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71062965/i-am-new-to-python-and-i-wonder-what-is-wrong-with-this-code/71063027#71063027

Comment: I suggest you edit your answer to include this or  maybe you can delete your answer as a more complete answer has already been posted

Answer (score 0):

`for item in number:` looks like you are attemping to repeat the loop `number` times. In python you do that like this: `for item in range(0, number):`. `item` will range from `0` to `number-1`

Comment: Andy Brown, Thanks!

Comment: While this does solve one part of the answer, a more complete answer has been posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71062965/i-am-new-to-python-and-i-wonder-what-is-wrong-with-this-code/71063027#71063027. I suggest you edit your answer to include this or delete it as a more complete answer has already been posted

Answer (score 0):

actually number is an integer, the error is saying in line 3 you are trying to loop through an integer which is not possible

Wrong : `for item in number`
What you may do instead : `for item in range(number)`

Here is some reading on the range function https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp

Comment: While this does get rid of the error, it doesn't solve the 2 other problems with the return from the function and the `name[1]` to `name[0]`, I suggest you either edit your answer to include this, or just delete your answer as a more complete answer has already been posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71062965/i-am-new-to-python-and-i-wonder-what-is-wrong-with-this-code/71063027#71063027