# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable (please help )

Tags: python

```
student_heights = input("Input a list of student heights ").split()
for n in range(0, len(student_heights)):
    student_heights[n] = int(student_heights[n])

total_height = 0
for height in total_height:
    total_height += height
print(total_height)

number_of_students = 0
for student in number_of_students:
    number_of_students += student
print(number_of_students)

avg_height = round(total_height / number_of_students)
print(avg_height)
```

i tried to make an avg height calculator but something isnt working

Comment: You really should provide more details. That said, `number_of_students` is an int (0), so the next line would expand to `for student in 0:` which is incorrect

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941288/how-do-i-fix-typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable

Answer (score 1):

You can do the split and parsing to `int` easier with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```py
student_heights = list(map(int, input("Input a list of student heights ").split()))
```

Then, you do not have to iterate over the list, but use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and `len`:

```py
avg_height = round(sum(student_heights) / len(student_heights))
```

The `TypeError` you are getting is caused because you want to iterate in a for loop over `total_height` and `number_of_students` and they are `int`s, so it's not possible - you have to use `iterable` object for this.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to iterate through integers, which isn't iterable.

Try this code:

```
student_heights = input("Input a list of student heights ").split()
for n in range(0, len(student_heights)):
student_heights[n] = int(student_heights[n])

total_height = 0
for n in range(0, len(student_heights)):
total_height += student_heights[n]
print(total_height)

number_of_students = 0
for n in range(0, len(student_heights)):
number_of_students += 1
print(number_of_students)

avg_height = round(total_height / number_of_students)
print(avg_height)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterator through list instead of variable `int` you just defined. Example.

```
student_heights = input("Input a list of student heights ").split()
for n in range(0, len(student_heights)):
    student_heights[n] = int(student_heights[n])

total_height = 0
for height in student_heights:
    total_height += height
print(total_height)

number_of_students = 0
for student in student_heights:
    number_of_students = number_of_students  + 1
print(number_of_students)

avg_height = round(total_height / number_of_students)
print(avg_height)
```