# Multiprocessing - cannot write list to csv (TypeError: 'ApplyResult' object is not iterable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a script for analyzing big csv files so I needed to start multiprocessing. I used `multiprocessing` module and it works fine but if I try to write the output list to a csv file, it throws an error:

```
TypeError: 'ApplyResult' object is not iterable
```

I looked up on some solutions including [multiprocessing: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884175/multiprocessing-typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable) but could not solve the problem.
Here is the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import csv
pool = Pool()

nodes = [['1001', '2008-01-06T02:12:13Z', ['']],
        ['1002', '2008-01-06T02:13:55Z', ['']],
        ['1003', '2008-01-06T02:13:00Z',  ['Lion', 'Rhinoceros', 'Leopard', 'Panda']],
        ['1004', '2008-01-06T02:15:20Z', ['Lion', 'Leopard', 'Eagle', 'Panda', 'Tiger']],
        ['1005', '2008-01-06T02:15:48Z', ['Lion', 'Panda', 'Cheetah', 'Goat', 'Tiger']],
        ['1006', '2008-01-06T02:13:30Z', ['']],
        ['1007', '2008-01-06T02:13:38Z', ['Cheetah', 'Tiger', 'Goat']]]

def nodes_to_links(nodes_list):
    output_list = []
    for ii, elem in enumerate(nodes_list[:-1]):
        for jj in range(ii + 1, len(nodes_list)):
            common = set(elem[-1]).intersection(
                set(nodes_list[jj][-1]))
            if len(common) > 0 and common != {''}:
                output_list.append([elem[0], nodes_list[jj][0], ','.join(map(str, list(common)))])
    return output_list

#links = nodes_to_links(nodes) ###This works perfect without multiprocessing
links = pool.apply_async(nodes_to_links, (nodes))  ### This works if I don't write the list "links" to a csv, but not otherwise

# Write links to a csv file
def writeCSV(list_to_write, OutputFileName):
    file = open(OutputFileName, 'w', newline='')
    writer = csv.writer(file, quotechar='"', delimiter=';',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in list_to_write:
        writer.writerow(row)

writeCSV(links,'output_files/test.csv')
```

I tried to use `pool.join()` and `pool.close()` but that also does not help. Can anyone please help. As a note, the list `nodes` is very big and I am just giving an example here, so multiprocessing is essential. Also can I know how to specify number of processors if I have four cores and 8 threads in my CPU?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pool.apply_async` returns a [pool.AsyncResult](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) object. This object isn't iterable - instead you need to call its `get()` method - i.e. `writeCSV(links.get(),'output_files/test.csv')` (with optional timeout).

Comment: By using the get() method, it gets stuck at `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'nodes_to_links' on <module '__main__' from 'test.py'>` and then if I cancel the operation, it throws a long list of errors. Did that work for you @match?

Comment: The `Can't get attribute` error means that your Python Pool instance can't find the function to call. It has `test.py` loaded, but `test.py` doesn't define a `__main__` that has a `nodes_to_links`. Usually this means you have some kind of violation of the multiprocessing limits, especially if you're on Windows.

Comment: I hadn't actually run it - was just looking at the mp docs.

It looks like you have 2 other bugs - firstly `pool = Pool()` must come after `nodes` and `nodes_to_links` are defined, and secondly, the arguments for `apply_async` is a tuple, so you mean `pool.apply_async(nodes_to_links, (nodes,))`. Seems to work for me with those changes.