# Checking if a lists' items are in the same order in another list

Tags: python, list

I have a list, say `[1, 5, 2, 6, 2, 5, 1]`.
The items in this list are in the same order in this list: `[4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 2, 5, 1, 6, 2, 3]`

What's an easy way finding out if a 1-nested lists' items are in the same order in another 1-nested lists' items?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847386/testing-if-a-list-contains-another-list-with-python

Comment: @pcalcao: I want a boolean, not another list.

Comment: It should be trivial then to adjust the answer to the other question then.

Comment: @beary605 You get a boolean, False if it doesn't contain the list, and a list otherwise, should be trivial to make that True

Comment: Do the items of the first list have to appear consecutively in the second list?

Comment: @DSM: My answer is horribly wrong and I have deleted it. Thanks Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at the question I wrote this. Unlike some of the others that assume that the elements in the first array must occur in the second contiguously, this does not.

```
def in_order(a,b):
    j = iter(b)
    for i in a:
        while True:
            try:
                j_ = j.next()
            except StopIteration:
                return False
            if i == j_:
                break
    return True
```

The OP's example:

```
a = [1, 5, 2, 6, 2, 5, 1]
b = [4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 2, 5, 1, 6, 2, 3]
print in_order(a,b)
```

prints: `True`

Comment: D: Elegant answer. I assumed that elements were supposed to occur contiguously

Answer (score 0):

```
size = len(needle)
any(needle == haystack[i:i+size] for i in range(len(haystack) - size + 1))
```

Answer (score -1):

Just modify the top answer from here: [Testing if a list contains another list with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847386/testing-if-a-list-contains-another-list-with-python)

Comment: I am adding +1 for simple fact that when downvoting people should provide a comment that should be helpful to the user

Comment: @pyfunc I downvoted for copy/paste from duplicate answer already posted

Comment: If this answer solves the question (which isn't clear until the OP clarifies it), then the question should be marked as a duplicate of the other one rather than copy/pasting the answer from there.

Comment: @NominSim: Sorry. But we should provide the comment. Thanks for coming back. Yeah, we do not want repeated answers in SO. We should just point out in that case

Comment: I have flagged the question as a duplicate...

Comment: @pyfunc I actually wasn't sure of the etiquette of copy/pasting an answer from a duplicate question so went to meta to check before coming back to explain the DV.