# checking to see if same value in two lists

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists one :

`[(12,23),(12,45),(12,23),(2,5),(1,2),(2,4),(7,34)]` which goes up to around 1000 elements
and another:

`[(12,23),(12,45),(12,23),(2,5),(1,2),(2,66),(34,7)]` which goes up to around 241 elements.

What I want is to check to see if the lists contain any of the same elements and then put them in a new list.

so the new list becomes

`[(12,23),(12,45),(12,23),(2,5),(1,2)]`

Comment: As long as it the new list contains all the elements that are the same in both, oder doesn't matter

Comment: Possible duplicat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847386/testing-if-a-list-contains-another-list-with-python

Comment: @JohnSmith Also, just say a value occured 3 times in the first list and 2 times in the last list, how many times would it be in the newlist? Or does it not matter

Comment: @tostao I think this is asking for an intersection of lists which is different to that question

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/642763/422353

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This doesn't include duplicates

```
>>> A = [(12,23),(12,45),(12,23),(2,5),(1,2),(2,4),(7,34)]
>>> B = [(12,23),(12,45),(12,23),(2,5),(1,2),(2,66),(34,7)]
>>> set(B).intersection(A) # note: making the smaller list to a set is faster
set([(12, 45), (1, 2), (12, 23), (2, 5)])
```

Or

```
>>> A = [(12,23),(12,45),(12,23),(2,5),(1,2),(2,4),(7,34)]
>>> B = [(12,23),(12,45),(12,23),(2,5),(1,2),(2,66),(34,7)]
>>> filter(set(B).__contains__, A)
[(12, 23), (12, 45), (12, 23), (2, 5), (1, 2)]
```

This returns every item in `B` if it occured in `A`, which produces the result you give in the example, however the `set` is *probably* what you want.

Since I don't know exactly what you are using this for, I'll suggest one more solution which returns a list, containing the items that occur in both lists, the **minimum** amount of times they occurred in either list (unordered). This differs from the set solution above which only returns each item the number of times it occurred in the **other** and doesn't care how many times it occurred in the first. This uses [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) for the intersection of multisets.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> A = [(12,23),(12,45),(12,23),(2,5),(1,2),(2,4),(7,34)]
>>> B = [(12,23),(12,45),(12,23),(2,5),(1,2),(2,66),(34,7)]
>>> list((Counter(A) & Counter(B)).elements())
[(1, 2), (12, 45), (12, 23), (12, 23), (2, 5)]
```

Comment: Given that `B` is significantly smaller than `A`, I’d suggest you to exchange each other in the statements. Also, the filter method is way faster than the set intersection.

Comment: @poke good idea I've change them, I'll add a note too