# Update sqlite3 db from lists

Tags: python, list, sqlite

The columns in my table look like this:

Name1 | Name2 | Weight | Height | Number1 | Number2

Some of the Number1 and Number2 columns are Null, and I am only trying to update the Null rows only. To do this, I have 6 lists:

```
List1 contains the values in Name1, in the same order
List2 contains the values in Name2, in the same order
List3 contains the values in Name1, but in a different order
List4 contains the values in Name2, but in the same order as List3
```

Lists 5 and 6 contains the values to be inserted in Number1 and Number2 respectively, and are in the same order as Lists 3 and 4.

So what I am trying to do is:

1. search the table for all the rows with Null values in Number1 AND Number2;
2. search Lists 3 OR 4 for values to match Name1 OR Name2, so if a match is found in list 3, the values for Number1 and Number2 should still be filled in from lists 5 and 6, respectively.

So the code I'm thinking of looks something like this:

```
for i in Name1:
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE Number1 IS NULL")
    if Name1 is List3:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO Mytable (Number1, Number2)" " VALUES (?, ?)",
(List5[i], List6[i]))
    elif Name2 is List4:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO Mytable (Number1, Number2)" " VALUES (?, ?)",
(List5[i], List6[i]))
```

However, when I run it, it adds rows to the table, but no values for Number1 or Number2. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> Where am I going wrong?

Probably here:

```
if Name1 is List3:
[...]
elif Name2 is List4:
```

The `is` keyword tests for [object identity](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons), which isn't what you want here. And even the test for equality won't help you here, as the order in both lists are different.

```
>>> a = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> b = a
>>> a is b
True
>>> a = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> b = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> a is b
False
>>> a == b
True
>>> b = ["b", "c", "a"]
>>> a == b
False
```

The resulting behaviour is that none of your `if` branches is executed. To achieve your goal you need to test if both lists contain the same members:

[Testing if a list contains another list with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847386/testing-if-a-list-contains-another-list-with-python)

However, your question is unclear about the exact condition: Are Name1/List3 and Name2/List4 supposed to contain **exactly** the same members, or is it sufficient for one member to be contained in the other? You might be able to figure the solution out yourself; if not I suggest you open another question on this specific problem.