# List in another list

Tags: python

```
def list(small,big):
    for i in range(len(big)):
        if small[i]!=big[i]:
            break

    else:
        return False
```

hi, i am new to python. I want to find if the numbers in a list are in another list. so [7,8,4] and [8,5,1] are subsequence of [7,8,5,4,1] and should return `True`, but [7,8,8] and [7,1,8] are not and should return `False`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you provide  an example with desired input and output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing if a list contains another list with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847386/testing-if-a-list-contains-another-list-with-python)

Comment: This is not a test of a sub-sequence inside a list.  For example, 8,5,1 does not occur in 7,8,5,4,1.  One must consider the '4' or any other number or group of numbers.

Comment: You should add more requirements or description to your problem, does the order matter?,

Comment: Does the order of the numbers matter?

Answer (score 0):

something like this would work
Since you are a newbie and building on your function idea

```
def lister(small,big):
    for i in range(len(small)):
        if small[i] not in big:
            return False
    return True

print(lister([1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5]))
```

define your function as `lister` since list is already a built in function in python

Edit: to Find a subsequence, It believe it can be done as follows:

```
def lister(small,big):
    for i in range(len(small)):
        if small[i] not in big:
            return False
    if  " ".join([str(x) for x in small]) in str(" ".join([str(y) for y in big])):
        return True
    else:
        return False


print(lister([3,5],[1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Comment: That gives True for print(lister([7,1,8],[7,8,5,4,1])).

Comment: thanks Sir. But actually, if i compare [1,2,2] with [1,2,3,4,5] , it returns True , as it is not a subsequence, so it should have been False

Comment: answer edited..I think comparing two sets will compare subsequences in specific order and out of order.....

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive approach. It works for all of your examples. Basically list1 is a subsequence of list2 if A) the first element of list1 is in list2 and B) the remainder of list1 is a subsequence of the remainder of list2.

```
def subsequence(list1, list2):
     if not list1:
             return True
     head, *tail = list1
     try:
             index = list2.index(head)
             return subsequence(tail, list2[index+1:])
     except ValueError:
             return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
def IsListInList(listA, listB):
    res = False
    for index,val in enumerate(listA):
        if (val in listB):
            listB = listB[listB.index(val)+1:]
            res = True
        else:
            res = False
            break
    return res
```