# Find the indices of list items in another list only when consecutive

Tags: python

I earlier asked this question and the following was suggested:
[How to test if a list contains another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847386/how-to-test-if-a-list-contains-another-list/3847612#3847612)
However, the above did not answer my question.

```
listA=["mango","orange","guava","mango","cherry","pawpaw"]
listB=["mango","cherry","pawpaw"]
```

In the lists A and B above, to get the indices of listB elements in listA, I want the indices of `"mango","cherry"` and `"pawpaw"` in listA to be `[3,4,5]` ignoring the first `"mango"` since it is not part of the consecutive sequence.

Comment: How big do your lists get, is performance of the code an issue?

Comment: It is not clear why the linked post does not solve your problem. It is not clear what you tried and did not succeed.

Comment: Why does the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847386/how-to-test-if-a-list-contains-another-list/3847612#3847612 not answer your question? As far as I see, it's exactly the same question, except that you are working with strings and are asking for explicit indices instead of range.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test if a list contains another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847386/how-to-test-if-a-list-contains-another-list)

Comment: @Tom S. The maximum length of the main list is 15

Comment: Then I do not see a problem with what everyone else has suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a sliding window of length equal to the length of `listB`

```
for i in range(len(listA)- len(listB) + 1):
    if listA[i:i+len(listB)] == listB:
        print([k for k in range(i,i+len(listB))])
```