# Almost there, but keep failing with one test

Tags: python, for-loop

I've got a question that is to take a list of one or more ints 'nums' and returns True if the sequence `[2, 4, 6]` appears in the list somewhere and False otherwise.
Here's my function so far:

```
def has246(nums):
    num = ""
    for i in nums:
        num += str(i)
    if "2" "4" "6" in num:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

For the following tests i get the expected result:

```
print(has246(\[2, 2, 4, 6, 2\]))
True
print(has246(\[2, 2, 4, 8, 2\]))
False
print(has246(\[2, 4\]))
False
```

But I get True for the following when the expected is False:

```
print(has246(\[24, 6\]))
False
```

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847386/how-to-test-if-a-list-contains-another-list-as-a-contiguous-subsequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try searching for actual numbers instead of converting to strings

```
def has246(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums) - 2):
        if nums[i:i+3] == [2, 4, 6]:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: `if nums[i:i+3] == [2, 4, 6]`…

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that you are joining the elements directly. So `[24, 6]` when joined becomes `'246'` returning `True`. The best solution would be to join the code with a delimiter as:

```
def has246(nums):
    num = ""
    for i in nums:
        num += str(i) +' ' # I have used space, you can use a '-' as well
    if "2 " "4 " "6 " in num:
        return True
        
    else:
        return False
print(has246([2, 2, 4, 6, 2]))
print(has246([2, 2, 4, 8, 2]))
print(has246([2, 4]))
print(has246([24, 6]))
```

This way joining the values gives you `'24 6'` instead of `'246'` and prevents the mistake by searching for `'2 4 6 '`
Output:

```
True
False
False
False
```

Comment: `num = ' '.join(map(str, nums))`…

Comment: `"2 " "4 " "6 "` is equivalent to `"2 4 6 "`…

Comment: @deceze I  know that, that is what prevents returning `True` for the last case. Otherwise, It will always return `False` since `'246'` doesn't exist in `'2 2 4 6 2 '`