# how to find a sequence of characters in an array and know how many times it appeared

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, any, findelement

Please, I need help finding out if the sequence in my array is present in another array, but I need to know how many times this same sequence has been found. I have this but it only returns if found only once.

```py
mylist = ['A','V','V']
# this array contains the sequence 'A','V','V' twice:
listfull = ['A','V','V','V','V','V','E','A','V','V'] 
n = len(mylist ) 
return any(mylist  == listfull [i:i + n] for i in range(len(listfull )-n + 1))
```

but what I need is to know how many times it appeared in the listfull

Comment: Are the list items always single character strings?

Comment: if you replace `any(...)` with `[...]` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24634740/740553, you now have a list of True and False values. You should be able to take it from there.

Comment: take @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans's advice and replace `any()` with `sum()` as summing a list of Booleans will tell you how many were True.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I need to know how many times this same sequence has been found. ..."*

Traverse *a*, qualifying each *slice*; from *i* to *i + n*.

```py
a = ['A','V','V','V','V','V','E','A','V','V']
n = len(b := ['A','V','V'])
x = 0
for i in range(len(a) - n + 1):
    if a[i:i + n] == b: x += 1
```

Output

```
2
```