# Is there a Python builtin for determining if an iterable contained a certain sequence?

Tags: python

For example, something like:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3].contains_sequence([1, 2])
True
>>> [1, 2, 3].contains_sequence([4])
False
```

I know that the `in` operator can do this for strings:

```
>>> "12" in "123"
True
```

But I'm looking for something that operates on iterables.

Comment: May the sequence appear anywhere inside the other sequence?

Comment: Yes — the operation I have in mind is identical to the behaviour of the `in` operator on strings, except for generic iterables.

Comment: Right to be sure - both sequences aren't iterables?

Comment: The haystack is an iterable, but there's no sense in requiring the needle to be an iterable (it would have to be unrolled anyway, as far as I can tell).

Comment: Yes, but have met some insane clients :) ie, "surely you can change our 57 table database with 200 millions rows before tomorrow" :)

Comment: Okay, just realised it's just after 5am and I need to get ready for work in a bit, and been on the PC all night :(

So if you don't get an acceptable answer, it'll be niggling at the back of my brown, but otherwise look forward to seeing one. GL

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Way To Determine if a Sequence is in another sequence in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425604/best-way-to-determine-if-a-sequence-is-in-another-sequence-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referenced from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6822773/24718
modified to use a list.

```
from itertools import islice

def window(seq, n=2):
    """
    Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the iterable
    s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...                   
    """
    it = iter(seq)
    result = list(islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield result    
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + [elem]
        yield result

def contains_sequence(all_values, seq):
    return any(seq == current_seq for current_seq in window(all_values, len(seq)))            

test_iterable = [1,2,3]
search_sequence = [1,2]

result = contains_sequence(test_iterable, search_sequence)
```

Answer (score 3):

Is there a Python builtin?  No.  You can accomplish this task in various ways.  [Here is a recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577850-search-sequences-for-sub-sequence/) that does it, and also gives you the position of the subsequence in the containing sequence:

```
def _search(forward, source, target, start=0, end=None):
    """Naive search for target in source."""
    m = len(source)
    n = len(target)
    if end is None:
        end = m
    else:
        end = min(end, m)
    if n == 0 or (end-start) < n:
        # target is empty, or longer than source, so obviously can't be found.
        return None
    if forward:
        x = range(start, end-n+1)
    else:
        x = range(end-n, start-1, -1)
    for i in x:
        if source[i:i+n] == target:
            return i
    return None
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the actual question ("is there a builtin") before providing an implementation.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there's no way to do this.  You can roll your own function pretty easily, but I doubt that will be terribly efficient.

```
>>> def contains_seq(seq,subseq):
...     #try: junk=seq[:]
...     #except: seq=tuple(seq)
...     #try: junk=subseq[:]
...     #except: subseq=tuple(subseq)
...     ll=len(subseq)
...     for i in range(len(seq)-ll):  #on python2, use xrange.
...         if(seq[i:i+ll] == subseq):
...             return True
...     return False
...
>>> contains_seq(range(10),range(3)) #True
>>> contains_seq(range(10),[2,3,6]) #False
```

Note that this solution does not work with generator type objects (it only works on objects that you can slice).  You could check `seq` to see if it is sliceable before proceeding and cast to a `tuple` if it isn't sliceable -- But then you get rid of the benefits of slicing.  You could re-write it to check one element at a time instead of using slicing, but I have a feeling performance would suffer even more.

Comment: Thanks for answering the actual question ("is there a builtin") before providing an implementation.

Comment: This requires both `seq` and `subseq` to be sequence-like (and not just iterable) -- i.e., `contains_seq(xrange(10), range(3))` won't work.

Comment: @mgilson: don't you mean "on python 2, use xrange"?

Comment: @EdwardLoper -- That's true.  I actually thought of that.  strictly speaking, I would consider `xrange` to be an `iterable` and not a `sequence` ( http://docs.python.org/glossary.html ).  Personally, I think this function should probably only support sequences for reasons I added above.

Comment: @mgilson The question title explicitly specifies that we should search inside an iterable, and David reiterated that in the comments for the question: "The haystack is an iterable, but there's no sense in requiring the needle to be an iterable."

Comment: @EdwardLoper -- Yes, I know that's what was asked for.  (and I provided a blurb on how to make my function work with arbitrary iterables).  However, I still think that it is either error prone or inefficient to support arbitrary iterables in this case .

Comment: @mgilson it's true — supporting only lists is both simpler and (could be, at least) faster. However, given that I need something which operates on iterables, it is also incorrect =\

Comment: @DavidWolever -- This doesn't just work on lists, it also works on tuples and strings and anything else that you can slice.  I added try/except clauses to make it work with other things (by converting them to tuples).

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, there's no builtin for this.  Here's an implementation that is potentially more efficient than the other answers I've seen -- in particular, it scans through the iterable, just keeping track of what prefix sizes of the target sequence it's seen.  But that increased efficiency comes at some expense in increased verbosity over some of the other approaches that have been suggested.

```
def contains_seq(iterable, seq):
    """
    Returns true if the iterable contains the given sequence.
    """
    # The following clause is optional -- leave it if you want to allow `seq` to
    # be an arbitrary iterable; or remove it if `seq` will always be list-like.
    if not isinstance(seq, collections.Sequence):
        seq = tuple(seq)

    if len(seq)==0: return True # corner case

    partial_matches = []
    for elt in iterable:
        # Try extending each of the partial matches by adding the
        # next element, if it matches.
        partial_matches = [m+1 for m in partial_matches if elt == seq[m]]
        # Check if we should start a new partial match
        if elt==seq[0]:
            partial_matches.append(1)
        # Check if we have a complete match (partial_matches will always
        # be sorted from highest to lowest, since older partial matches 
        # come before newer ones).
        if partial_matches and partial_matches[0]==len(seq):
            return True
    # No match found.
    return False
```

Comment: I don't think I would use the `hasattr` bit.  You pick up the ability to check `sets` and maybe some user defined objects, but I wouldn't typically expect an object which doesn't support `__getitem__` to be ordered.  I think it's better to force the user to explicitly cast to a different object -- although I suppose it does allow the use of generators, etc (but casts away all of their benefits)...

Comment: The `hasattr` bit was put in to allow `seq` (the "needle") to be any arbitrary iterable, if that was desired -- e.g., `contains_seq(xrange(100), xrange(3,8))`.  If it's known that the needle is list-like, then you can get rid of that.

Comment: The `hasattr` check would be better spelled as: `if not isinstance(seq, collections.Sequence)` (although that has slightly different semantics, so you might also want to check against `collections.Mapping`). And it should really go *before* the check for an empty sequence.

Answer (score 2):

If preserving of order is not necessary, you can use sets (builtin):

```
>>> set([1,2]).issubset([1,2,3])
True
>>> set([4]).issubset([1,2,3])
False
```

Otherwise:

```
def is_subsequence(sub, iterable):
    sub_pos, sub_len = 0, len(sub)
    for i in iterable:
        if i == sub[sub_pos]:
            sub_pos += 1
            if sub_pos >= sub_len:
                return True
        else:
            sub_pos = 0
    return False

>>> is_subsequence([1,2], [0,1,2,3,4])
True
>>> is_subsequence([2,1], [0,1,2,3,4]) # order preserved
False
>>> is_subsequence([1,2,4], [0,1,2,3,4])
False
```

This one works with any iterator.

Comment: @mgilson, thanks for comment! Another variant was added - it works with iterables and preserves order of subsequence.

Answer (score 2):

[deque](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#deque-objects) appears to be useful here:

```
from collections import deque

def contains(it, seq):
    seq = deque(seq)
    deq = deque(maxlen=len(seq))
    for p in it:
        deq.append(p)
        if deq == seq:
            return True
    return False
```

Note that this accepts arbitrary iterables for both arguments (no slicing required).

Answer (score 1):

As there's no builtin, I made a nice version:

```
import itertools as it

def contains(seq, sub):
    seq = iter(seq)
    o = object()
    return any(all(i==j for i,j in zip(sub, it.chain((n,),seq, 
                                      (o for i in it.count())))) for n in seq)
```

This *do not require any extra lists* (if you use `it.izip` or Py3k).

```
>>> contains([1,2,3], [1,2])
True
>>> contains([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
True
>>> contains([1,2,3], [2,3])
True
>>> contains([1,2,3], [2,3,4])
False
```

Extra points if you have no trouble reading it. (It does the job, but the implementation is not to be taked too seriously). ;)

Answer (score -2):

You could convert it into a string and then do matching on it

```
full_list = " ".join([str(x) for x in [1, 2, 3]])
seq = " ".join([str(x) for x in [1, 2]])
seq in full_list
```

Comment: This would only work if the items can be sensibly converted to strings.

Comment: Yes, but the example given was for integers, which can be converted into string pretty easily. Not only that, using str.join and then the in operator is a very efficient way to do this, since str.join is an efficient operation compared to iterating the list.

Comment: This would also give the True for the input `['list','one','list','two']`, seaching for `['list one','list two']`.  While a rare case, it's still worth mentioning.

Comment: Yes, but the example is just an example. Both the title and the last paragraph make it clear that I'm interested in generic iterables. Additionally, the methods you've proposed are incorrect, even when the input is only integers: consider the case where I want to determine whether `[12]` contains the sequence `[1]` (or determine whether `["foobar"]` contains `["foo"]`).

Comment: Ah that true, I didn't think about any of those cases