# Python: Find index of fist list in list oneliner

Tags: python, list, find

Here's the solution to find y list index in x big list

```
def getsubidx(x, y):
    l1, l2 = len(x), len(y)
    for i in range(l1):
        if x[i:i+l2] == y:
            return i
```

Is it possible to transform this to oneliner using itertools, filter or something else?

Answer (score 1):

```
def getsubidx(x, y):
    return next(i for i in range(len(x)) if x[i:i+len(y)] == y)
```

You may want an error to be raised if no match, if you don't you can return `-1`

```
return next((i for i in range(len(x)) if x[i:i+len(y)] == y), -1)
```

Comment: I assumed OP would want an error, if OP doesn't -1 can be a default value

Answer (score 0):

```
def getsubidx(x, y):
    l1, l2 = len(x), len(y)
    for i in range(l1-l2):   here it should be l1-l2
        if x[i:i+l2] == y:        here you may get list out of index
            return i
```

one liner:

```
def getsubidx(x, y):
    return [i for i in range(len(x)-len(y)) if x[i:i+len(y)] == y]
```

Comment: This finds every index in a list , not what the question shows

Comment: Also you won't **ever** get a list out of index for a slice like that `>>> [][9000:9001]`
`[]`

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to transform this to oneliner using itertools, filter or something else?

Here's *"somethng else"*, you could use [`index(subseq, seq)` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/426168/4279):

```
index_of_y_in_x = index(y, x)
```